# Switch statement fallthrough in C#?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Switch statement fallthrough is one of my personal major reasons for loving `switch` vs. `if/else if` constructs. An example is in order here:

```
static string NumberToWords(int number)
{
    string[] numbers = new string[] 
        { "", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", 
          "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };
    string[] tens = new string[] 
        { "", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", 
          "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" };
    string[] teens = new string[]
        { "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen",
          "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen" };

    string ans = "";
    switch (number.ToString().Length)
    {
        case 3:
            ans += string.Format("{0} hundred and ", numbers[number / 100]);
        case 2:
            int t = (number / 10) % 10;
            if (t == 1)
            {
                ans += teens[number % 10];
                break;
            }
            else if (t > 1)
                ans += string.Format("{0}-", tens[t]);
        case 1:
            int o = number % 10;
            ans += numbers[o];

            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("number");
    }
    return ans;
}
```

The smart people are cringing because the `string[]`s should be declared outside the function: well, they are, this is just an example.

The compiler fails with the following error:

```
Control cannot fall through from one case label ('case 3:') to another
Control cannot fall through from one case label ('case 2:') to another
```

Why? And is there any way to get this sort of behaviour without having three `if`s?

Answer (score 739, accepted):

(Copy/paste of an [answer I provided elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c/90432#90432))

Falling through `switch`-`case`s can be achieved by having no code in a `case` (see `case 0`), or using the special `goto case` (see `case 1`) or `goto default` (see `case 2`) forms:

```
switch (/*...*/) {
    case 0: // shares the exact same code as case 1
    case 1:
        // do something
        goto case 2;
    case 2:
        // do something else
        goto default;
    default:
        // do something entirely different
        break;
}
```

Comment: I think that, in this particular instance, goto is not considered harmful.

Comment: @Atømix: Yes, probably.  But it's nothing that a hot shower and some refactoring won't fix :P

Comment: I never thought I'll ever use `goto` statement in my life after I last used it back in the 80' in some obscure Turbo Pascal 3 function. :) This saved me a few minutes actually.

Comment: Would it be overkill to create a new reserved word `fallthrough` that you could use to indicate an explicit desire to allow fall through. The compiler could then check for accidental fall through, but allow purposeful usage.

Comment: @Dancrumb: At the time that the feature was written, C# had not yet added any "soft" keywords (like 'yield', 'var', 'from', and 'select'), so they had three real options: 1) make 'fallthrough' a hard keyword (you cant use it as a variable name), 2) write code necessary to support such an soft keyword, 3) use already reserved keywords. #1 was a big issue for those porting code; #2 was a fairly large engineering task, from what I understand; and the option they went with, #3 had a side benefit: other devs reading the code after the fact could learn about the feature from the base concept of goto

Comment: That code didn't work for me (in Visual Studio 2010), I still have the compiler error "Control cannot fall through from one case label ('case 1:') to another". I even added a `break;` statement after the goto and now I just have a warning (unreachable code detected) along with the error.

Comment: @EastofNowhere Make sure that you've got a case that reads "case 2:" can not something else -- this has worked since .NET 1.0, and still works in VS2012 with .NET 4.5.

Comment: I haven't explored this in detail, but I was still receiving this error, even with a goto, when I was switching on a string, instead of an integer value.

Comment: @Jeff Dege - if you're switching on a string, your `goto` statement for `case("XYZ"):` should be written `goto case ("XYZ");`

Comment: All this talk about new/special keywords for an explicit fallthrough. Couldn't they just have used the 'continue' keyword? In other words. Break out of the switch or continue onto the next case (fall through).

Comment: @TalEven-Tov What if the `switch` is inside a loop?

Comment: @Rawling. Good point. The proposed continue would be constrained to the scope of the case only.

Comment: I hate, hate, HATE this.  Not a reflection on the question or answer, I just hate the fact that this is necessary in C#.

Comment: @scott.korin Why?  Would you prefer implicit fall-through?  I'm pretty sure that the last 30 years of C-like language usage has told us how horrible an idea that is.  The only other real option is not even supporting this, and forcing either code duplication, or (gasp) standard goto-labels.

Comment: @AlexLyman: How about a `join case` statement which would behave like `case` except that the previous case would fall through?  I would think that cleaner than a `goto` which targets the next executable statement, but it would avoid all the problems associated with implicit fall-through.

Comment: This should still avoided when possible. Cases will not always be linearly like this example, and if someone ever shuffles their order around in the switch statement you'll find yourself jumping over cases instead of falling through.

Comment: goto has its perfectly legal and elegant uses other than this.

Comment: The compiler will convert your case fall throughs into goto statements anyway, personally I'm not a fan of case fall through, it seems vague and hacky to me.

Comment: @Rawling What if you use `switch` inside a loop and want to use `break`?

Comment: @NetMage `break` will work for the `switch`, not the loop, and I don't think C# has a way around that if you want it to work for the loop.

Comment: @Rawling I know - which is why I think `continue` working the same way would be perfectly acceptable (re: your comment above 6 years ago ;) ).

Comment: @NetMage Unfortunately, because that was not the original implementation, there would be compatibility issues if added now. Someone somewhere has code that uses continue for their loop inside of a switch statement.

Comment: @nrylee True, but `break` is already scoped to the nearest enclosing `switch` or loop, changing `continue` the same way would at least be consistent, if a bit late. I would guess `continue` in a switch isn't terribly common today.

Comment: @NetMage Truly, I think having `continue` in a `switch` statement would have been an even more clear statement than `fallthrough`. And yes, `continue` is probably sitting inside of a `switch` statement in a single line of code that currently exists in the world. Unfortunately, that code is probably critical infrastructure that would cause a million people to go broke, starve, or be poisoned if the compiler logic changed.

Comment: @nrylee I like C# a lot (though Microsoft makes me sad sometimes) but any critical code like that would be written in COBOL or worse.

Comment: I still don't get this. Why not allow it with something like an attribute as C++17 does.
And @AlexLyman the porting code argument doesn't cut it with me. No two languages are free from this problem that you wouldn't want an automated string replacement routine in porting.

Comment: A popular misconception is that "GOTO is EVIL and B.A.D.".  That, however, was never the problem.  The problem was the flagrant *overuse* of GOTO when there were better available structured alternatives.  There is nothing wrong with using GOTO if it's *necessary*.  I've seen many programmers fret and ponder for days to get around using one GOTO.  There's not a law.  If GOTO were really that terrible, the language *designers* would simply leave it out.  They've kept it for all these years for one very simple and logical reason.  Sometimes it's the best alternative.

Comment: @ThomasOwens goto isn't harmful outside of a switch anyway.  I have no idea why goto is so frowned upon when it serves a very useful purpose.  People say that it leads to spaghetti code, but it really doesn't, if used responsibly.

Comment: I recall seeing `continue` suggested for this before.  Possibly for D rather than C#.  The problem is that this already means continue to the next iteration of the enclosing loop, including within a `switch`.  Admittedly this is an inconsistency between `break` and `continue` when they occur in a `switch`, but I suspect this originated in C, and I'm not sure whether C# is designed with a "looks like C, acts like C" principle.  In any case, changing `continue` now to mean fall through to the next `case` would change the behaviour of existing code.

Comment: This said, I'm made to wonder why both C# and D kept the C `switch` syntax rather than inventing a new syntax, maybe with `case` as a block or something.  It could maybe allow cases to be nested in a way that generalises the concept of fallthrough.

Answer (score 56):

The "why" is to avoid accidental fall-through, for which I'm grateful. This is a not uncommon source of bugs in C and Java.

The workaround is to use goto, e.g.

```
switch (number.ToString().Length)
{
    case 3:
        ans += string.Format("{0} hundred and ", numbers[number / 100]);
        goto case 2;
    case 2:
    // Etc
}
```

The general design of switch/case is a little bit unfortunate in my view. It stuck too close to C - there are some useful changes which could be made in terms of scoping etc. Arguably a smarter switch which could do pattern matching etc would be helpful, but that's really changing from switch to "check a sequence of conditions" - at which point a different name would perhaps be called for.

Comment: This is the difference between switch and if/elseif in my mind. Switch is for checking various states of a single variable, whereas if/elseif can be used to check any number of things that connected, but not necessarily a single, or the same variable.

Comment: If it was to prevent accidental fall through then I feel a compiler warning would have been better. Just like you have one if your if statement has an assignment: `if (result =  true) { }`

Comment: @TalEven-Tov: Compiler warnings should really be for cases where you can almost always fix the code to be better. Personally I'd prefer implicit breaking, so it wouldn't be a problem to start with, but that's a different matter.

Comment: The annoying thing is that they still make you end the cases with `break`.

Comment: Newer versions of C# have mercifully added pattern matching switch statements.

Answer (score 33):

To add to the answers here, I think it's worth considering the opposite question in conjunction with this, viz. why did C allow fall-through in the first place?

Any programming language of course serves two goals:

1. Provide instructions to the computer.
2. Leave a record of the intentions of the programmer.

The creation of any programming language is therefore a balance between how to best serve these two goals. On the one hand, the easier it is to turn into computer instructions (whether those are machine code, bytecode like IL, or the instructions are interpreted on execution) then more able that process of compilation or interpretation will be to be efficient, reliable and compact in output. Taken to its extreme, this goal results in our just writing in assembly, IL, or even raw op-codes, because the easiest compilation is where there is no compilation at all.

Conversely, the more the language expresses the intention of the programmer, rather than the means taken to that end, the more understandable the program both when writing and during maintenance.

Now, `switch` could always have been compiled by converting it into the equivalent chain of `if-else` blocks or similar, but it was designed as allowing compilation into a particular common assembly pattern where one takes a value, computes an offset from it (whether by looking up a table indexed by a perfect hash of the value, or by actual arithmetic on the value*). It's worth noting at this point that today, C# compilation will sometimes turn `switch` into the equivalent `if-else`, and sometimes use a hash-based jump approach (and likewise with C, C++, and other languages with comparable syntax).

In this case there are two good reasons for allowing fall-through:

1. It just happens naturally anyway: if you build a jump table into a set of instructions, and one of the earlier batches of instructions doesn't contain some sort of jump or return, then execution will just naturally progress into the next batch. Allowing fall-through was what would "just happen" if you turned the `switch`-using C into jump-table–using machine code.
2. Coders who wrote in assembly were already used to the equivalent: when writing a jump table by hand in assembly, they would have to consider whether a given block of code would end with a return, a jump outside of the table, or just continue on to the next block. As such, having the coder add an explicit `break` when necessary was "natural" for the coder too.

At the time therefore, it was a reasonable attempt to balance the two goals of a computer language as it relates to both the produced machine code, and the expressiveness of the source code.

Four decades later though, things are not quite the same, for a few reasons:

1. Coders in C today may have little or no assembly experience. Coders in many other C-style languages are even less likely to (especially Javascript!). Any concept of "what people are used to from assembly" is no longer relevant.
2. Improvements in optimisations mean that the likelihood of `switch` either being turned into `if-else` because it was deemed the approach likely to be most efficient, or else turned into a particularly esoteric variant of the jump-table approach are higher. The mapping between the higher- and lower-level approaches is not as strong as it once was.
3. Experience has shown that fall-through tends to be the minority case rather than the norm (a study of Sun's compiler found 3% of `switch` blocks used a fall-through other than multiple labels on the same block, and it was thought that the use-case here meant that this 3% was in fact much higher than normal). So the language as studied make the unusual more readily catered-to than the common.
4. Experience has shown that fall-through tends to be the source of problems both in cases where it is accidentally done, and also in cases where correct fall-through is missed by someone maintaining the code. This latter is a subtle addition to the bugs associated with fall-through, because even if your code is perfectly bug-free, your fall-through can still cause problems.

Related to those last two points, consider the following quote from the current edition of K&R:

> Falling through from one case to another is not robust, being prone to disintegration when the program is modified. With the exception of multiple labels for a single computation, fall-throughs should be used sparingly, and commented.
>
> As a matter of good form, put a break after the last case (the default here) even though it's logically unnecessary. Some day when another case gets added at the end, this bit of defensive programming will save you.

So, from the horse's mouth, fall-through in C is problematic. It's considered good practice to always document fall-throughs with comments, which is an application of the general principle that one should document where one does something unusual, because that's what will trip later examination of the code and/or make your code look like it has a novice's bug in it when it is in fact correct.

And when you think about it, code like this:

```
switch(x)
{
  case 1:
   foo();
   /* FALLTHRU */
  case 2:
    bar();
    break;
}
```

**Is** adding something to make the fall-through explicit in the code, it's just not something that can be detected (or whose absence can be detected) by the compiler.

As such, the fact that on has to be explicit with fall-through in C# doesn't add any penalty to people who wrote well in other C-style languages anyway, since they would already be explicit in their fall-throughs.†

Finally, the use of `goto` here is already a norm from C and other such languages:

```
switch(x)
{
  case 0:
  case 1:
  case 2:
    foo();
    goto below_six;
  case 3:
    bar();
    goto below_six;
  case 4:
    baz();
    /* FALLTHRU */
  case 5:
  below_six:
    qux();
    break;
  default:
    quux();
}
```

In this sort of case where we want a block to be included in the code executed for a value other than just that which brings one to the preceding block, then we're already having to use `goto`. (Of course, there are means and ways of avoiding this with different conditionals but that's true of just about everything relating to this question). As such C# built on the already normal way to deal with one situation where we want to hit more than one block of code in a `switch`, and just generalised it to cover fall-through as well. It also made both cases more convenient and self-documenting, since we have to add a new label in C but can use the `case` as a label in C#. In C# we can get rid of the `below_six` label and use `goto case 5` which is clearer as to what we are doing. (We'd also have to add `break` for the `default`, which I left out just to make the above C code clearly not C# code).

In summary therefore:

1. C# no longer relates to unoptimised compiler output as directly as C code did 40 years ago (nor does C these days), which makes one of the inspirations of fall-through irrelevant.
2. C# remains compatible with C in not just having implicit `break`, for easier learning of the language by those familiar with similar languages, and easier porting.
3. C# removes a possible source of bugs or misunderstood code that has been well-documented as causing problems for the last four decades.
4. C# makes existing best-practice with C (document fall through) enforceable by the compiler.
5. C# makes the unusual case the one with more explicit code, the usual case the one with the code one just writes automatically.
6. C# uses the same `goto`-based approach for hitting the same block from different `case` labels as is used in C. It just generalises it to some other cases.
7. C# makes that `goto`-based approach more convenient, and clearer, than it is in C, by allowing `case` statements to act as labels.

All in all, a pretty reasonable design decision

---

*Some forms of BASIC would allow one to do the likes of `GOTO (x AND 7) * 50 + 240` which while brittle and hence a particularly persuasive case for banning `goto`, does serve to show a higher-language equivalent of the sort of way that lower-level code can make a jump based on arithmetic upon a value, which is much more reasonable when it's the result of compilation rather than something that has to be maintained manually. Implementations of Duff's Device in particular lend themselves well to the equivalent machine code or IL because each block of instructions will often be the same length without needing the addition of `nop` fillers.

†Duff's Device comes up here again, as a reasonable exception. The fact that with that and similar patterns there's a repetition of operations serves to make the use of fall-through relatively clear even without an explicit comment to that effect.

Comment: I'm fairly sure BASICs vary in whether they allow computed `GOTO`.  The fragility of this - even more so if the BASIC in question has `RENUM` - is perhaps one motivation for allowing you to `GOTO` only a hardcoded line number.  I suspect some BASICs optimise the code in such a way that computed `GOTO` can't be easily implemented.
(If you dare, check out Come Here: http://wwwep.stewartsplace.org.uk/languages/comehere/)

Answer (score 27):

Switch fallthrough is historically one of the major source of bugs in modern softwares. The language designer decided to make it mandatory to jump at the end of the case, unless you are defaulting to the next case directly without processing.

```
switch(value)
{
    case 1:// this is still legal
    case 2:
}
```

Comment: I well never understand why that isn't "case 1, 2:"

Comment: @David Pfeffer: Yup it is, and so is `case 1, 2:` in languages that allow that. What I will never understand is why any modern language would't choose to allow that.

Comment: @BCS with the goto statement, multiple comma separated options could be tricky to handle?

Comment: @pengut: it might be more accurate to say that `case 1, 2:` is a single label but with multiple names. -- FWIW, I think most languages that forbid fall through don't special case the "consecutive case labels" indium but rather treat the case labels as an annotation on the next statement and require the last statement before a statement labeled with (one or more) case labels to be a jump.

Comment: @BCS in C and other C-Like lenguages (not sure about C#) comma (",") is an operator, so it is not good idea to redefine its behaviour just for this "case".

Comment: @Will: maybe, sort of. However, most such languages require the value of a `case` to be a compile time constant without side effects, and the primary (only?) use for the comma *expression* is to insert sub expressions strictly for their side effects. Also, there are other places where a comma is used that are not an operator (function arguments, arrays, object literals, `enum` definitions, variable declarations, etc. I don't think that will cause any real world problems.

Comment: Rust do allow that, it's `match value { 1 | 2 => ... }`.

Answer (score 18):

You can 'goto case label'
http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpGoto.aspx

> The goto statement is a simple command that unconditionally transfers the control of the program to another statement. The command is often criticised with some developers advocating its removal from all high-level programming languages because it can lead to [*spaghetti code*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code). This occurs when there are so many goto statements or similar jump statements that the code becomes difficult to read and maintain. However, there are programmers who point out that the goto statement, when used carefully, provides an elegant solution to some problems...

Answer (score 7):

They left out this behaviour by design to avoid when it was not used by will but caused problems.

It can be used only if there is no statement in the case part, like:

```
switch (whatever)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3: boo; break;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

They changed the switch statement (from C/Java/C++) behavior for c#.  I guess the reasoning was that people forgot about the fall through and errors were caused.  One book I read said to use goto to simulate, but this doesn't sound like a good solution to me.

Comment: C# supports goto, but not fallthrough? Wow. And it's not just those. C# is the only language that I know of that behaves this way.

Comment: I didn't exactly like it at first, but "fall-thru" is really a recipe for disaster (especially amongst junior programmers.) As many have pointed out, C# still allows fall-thru for empty lines (which is the majority of cases.) "Kenny" posted a link that highlights elegant Goto use with switch-case.

Comment: It's not a huge deal in my opinion.  99% of the time I don't want a fall through and I have been burned by bugs in the past.

Comment: "this doesn't sound like a good solution to me" -- sorry to hear that about you, because that's what `goto case` is for. Its advantage over fallthrough is that it is explicit. That some people here object to `goto case` just shows that they were indoctrinated against "goto" without any understanding of the issue and are incapable of thinking on their own. When Dijkstra wrote "GOTO Considered Harmful", he was addressing languages that didn't have any other means of changing control flow.

Comment: @JimBalter and then how many people who quote Dijkstra on that will quote Knuth that "premature optimisation is the root of all evil" though that quote was when Knuth was explicitly writing about how useful `goto` can be when optimising code?

Comment: @JonHanna Why, then, did he invoke "Hoare's dictum"? Knuth's paper was more about clarity than about optimization. The quote never actually appears in the paper; rather, he wrote "In our previous discussion we concluded that premature emphasis on efficiency is a big mistake which may well be the source of most
 programming complexity and grief".

Comment: @JimBalter The quote you give there appeared on p. 294 of the journal in question, with "premature optimization is the root of all evil" having indeed appeared on p. 268. The paper as a whole calls for a balanced view that eliminates `goto` in a lot of cases but accepts them in others, at least until languages and/or compilers remove the advantages they retain (still relevant today: e.g. with C# labelled break could arguably remove some of the remaining uses, while with the .NET jitter, more aggressive tail-call optimisation would remove its use for manual tail-call elimination).

Comment: @JimBalter As for "Hoare's dictum", Knuth referred to it as that some 15 years or so later. Hoare in turn denied memory of ever saying it and suggested (ironically enough) that it might have been Dijkstra's coinage. Either way, the thing I get most out of Knuth's paper that contains the earliest known version of it, is that thought for the consequences is more important than matching a great-sounding quote, anyway.

Comment: @JonHanna You're telling me stuff I already know, except that I missed the earlier quote. Yet more uses of goto could be eliminated with multi-level break/continue and with local functions, still not available in C# while in far older languages -- though closures finally making it into the "mainstream" languages (except C) can be used instead.

Comment: @JimBalter I thought I likely was, since my first comment was in support of yours, after all.

Answer (score 0):

[switch (C# Reference) says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx)

> C# requires the end of switch sections, including the final one,

So you also need to add a `break;` to your `default` section, otherwise there will still will be a compiler error.

Comment: It's one thing for a language to make a design decision to avoid programming pitfalls, but there is no way you can honestly say that permitting a fallthrough on the final statement could in any way be harmful.

Answer (score -1):

> A jump statement such as a break is
>   required after each case block,
>   including the last block whether it is
>   a case statement or a default
>   statement. With one exception, (unlike
>   the C++ switch statement), C# does not
>   support an implicit fall through from
>   one case label to another. The one
>   exception is if a case statement has
>   no code.

-- [C# switch() documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: I realise this behaviour is documented, I want to know WHY it is the way it is, and any alternatives to get the old behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

After each case statement require **break** or **goto** statement even if it is a default case.

Comment: If only someone had posted that two years earlier!

Comment: @Poldie it was funny the first time... Shilpa you don't require a break or goto for every case, just for every case with it's own code. You can have multiple cases that share code just fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve fall through like c++ by the goto keyword.

EX:

```
switch(num)
{
   case 1:
      goto case 3;
   case 2:
      goto case 3;
   case 3:
      //do something
      break;
   case 4:
      //do something else
      break;
   case default:
      break;
}
```

Comment: If only someone had posted that two years earlier!

Answer (score -1):

Just a quick note to add that the compiler for Xamarin actually got this wrong and it allows fallthrough. It has supposedly been fixed, but has not been released. Discovered this in some code that actually was falling through and the compiler did not complain.

Answer (score -1):

This post is about trying to justify why the disallowing of fall-through cases in a switch is not a nice thing.  I've also provided an example of where cascading fall-through of cases actually works really well and is particularly difficult to achieve with such good results any other way. Sure, It's a niche example, but it's still a worthy use-case.

The problem here with the disallowing of fall-through on cases within a switch, is that it prevents you being able to do certain loop-unrolls.  Whilst I can appreciate some of the other viewpoints here, I don't think that fall-through is intrinsically bad or requires a deeper level of understanding.

I ran into an interesting case where I really needed fall-through and having to use goto, almost seemed like a bit of a cludge. It was where I doing some bit manipulation and depending on how many bits that were left, I needed to cascade  through cases. This resulted in the following switch:

```
switch (bitsLeft % 11)
{
    case 10:
       store.Append((byte)data[3] << 3);
       goto case 9;
    case 9:
       store.Append((byte)(data[2] << 7 | data[4] >> 1));
       goto case 8;
    case 8:
       store.Append((byte)(data[0] >> 2 | data[1] >> 4));
       goto case 7;
    case 7:
       store.Append((byte)(data[4] << 6 | data[5] << 4));
       goto case 6;
    case 6:
       store.Append((byte)(data[6] << 7 | data[0] >> 5));
       goto case 5;
    case 5:
       store.Append((byte)data[7] << 1);
       goto case 4;
    case 4:
       store.Append((byte)(data[7] >> 2 | data[6] << 2));
       goto case 3;
    case 3:
       store.Append((byte)(data[8] << 3 | data[3] >> 5));
       goto case 2;
    case 2:
       store.Append((byte)(data[4] >> 1 | data[6] << 1));
       goto case 1;
    case 1:
       store.Append((byte)data[7] << 2 | data[2] << 1));
       break;
    default: break;
}
```

I just don't see how disallowing fall-through and being forced to use goto really adds anything, especially in situations where you want to cascade cases. Moreover, writing the above with if/else-if would amount to huge amounts of code duplication.

It's also hard to accept the reasoning that the lack of fall-through is due to the large amount of bugs caused by it. I put this reasoning into the same sort of category as using braces for single-line if statements. Using the practise of **always** adding braces **BEFORE** altering code below an if condition really prevents these kinds of bugs.

The same strategy can equally be applied to switch statements. When writing a switch, include all of the cases and add a *break;* for each. Only then that start implementing the code for each case.  There's never any risk that a case could fall-through because all cases have break statements right from the outset. Okay, it is possible that adding cases to a switch after implementation could lead to a forgotten break; but starting a case implementation with a break statement and writing code above it is always going to prevent accidental fall-through. Moreover, many switches have cases that are dependent on an enumeration, so providing empty cases with just a break before starting implementation is trivial.

My case is quite niche and disallowing of fall-through cases probably suits most people's needs, but it does seem a little harsh that it's not a configurable option.  Maybe using annotations would have been a better way to go?

Answer (score -12):

You forgot to add the "break;" statement into case 3. In case 2 you wrote it into the if block.
Therefore try this:

```
case 3:            
{
    ans += string.Format("{0} hundred and ", numbers[number / 100]);
    break;
}


case 2:            
{
    int t = (number / 10) % 10;            
    if (t == 1)            
    {                
        ans += teens[number % 10];                
    }            
    else if (t > 1)                
    {
        ans += string.Format("{0}-", tens[t]);        
    }
    break;
}

case 1:            
{
    int o = number % 10;            
    ans += numbers[o];            
    break;        
}

default:            
{
    throw new ArgumentException("number");
}
```

Comment: This produces vastly wrong output. I left the switch statements out by design. The question is why the C# compiler sees this as an error when almost no other language has this restriction.