# Javascript switch statement to excute some of the same functions depending on the case

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

In JavaScript, I am trying to write a switch statement that does something like the following -

```
swtich(n)
{
   case 1:
      functionW(); functionX(); functionY(); functionZ();
      break;
   case 2:
      functionX(); functionY(); functionZ();
      break;
   case 3:
      functionY(); functionZ();
      break;
   default:
      functionZ();
      break;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I chose the answer given by Frits because it will work when the "cases" are not numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `break`

The cases will *fallthrough*.

Make sure you explicitly note that you **don't** want to `break` because it may look like a bug.

```
switch(n)
{
   case 1:
      functionW();
      // dont break
   case 2:
      functionX();
      // dont break
   case 3:
      functionY();
      // dont break
   default:
      functionZ();
      // dont break
}
```

If `n` is `1` it will execute `functionW()` then fallthrough to `case 2` and execute `functionX();` and so on...

Comment: I'm not sure I would've thought of this, pretty cool. Not sure why this was downvoted either

Comment: @Ian because its brittle and is considered a bad practice. Also, there is often a much more clean way to do it. See longer discussions: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188461/switch-statement-fallthrough-should-it-be-allowed) and [nearby](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/116221/appropriate-uses-of-fall-through-switch-statements)

Comment: Some IDEs (e.g. PhpStorm/IDEAJ) will warn about switch without `break`. Is there a doc-comment way to tell them that it's OK?

Comment: @c69 If you think there is a cleaner way you're welcome to post your own answer. I'm excited to see what you come up with.

Comment: @c69 Hmm I never knew it was considered a bad practice, but then again I've never really needed to use `switch` statements or cared to look into that, but your links clearly show that's true. I understand it can be error-prone and isn't as readable, but I feel like one should learn the tools you use before using them - it might just be me, but it seems plenty fine to use fallthrough here,  probably because I'm not a newbie (which you mentioned). What would you suggest, `if` statements then?

Comment: I can't think of a cleaner way other than a bunch of `if`s

Comment: @FritsvanCampen in this case, Jacob gave the most explicit solution (group of `if`'s without else). But often in JS you can wrap `case` items into functions, so you will just call `action[2]()` or `action[name]()`. For other languages, or things like parsers, or contests (when the code length might matter) - switch is perfectly valid, and fallthrough is a tolerable hack. In short: your answer is correct, but hopefully the vocal -1 and the chain of comments will force the readers and googlers to think before using it.

Answer (score 2):

Frits van Campen's answer is the closes to the same exact functionality you described. I always have bugs when I use switch with/without fallthrough. If n is a number I'd use:

```
if(n >= 1){functionW();}
if(n >= 2){functionX();}
if(n >= 3){functionY();}
functionZ();
```

(I removed my second answer as Barmar expressed it better.)

**Edit:**

It can be modified to work with non-numbers:

```
var test = false
if(n === 1 || test){test = true; functionW();}
if(n === 2 || test){test = true; functionX();}
if(n === 3 || test){test = true; functionY();}
functionZ();
```

Comment: Your first option is by far the best among the presented here: it clearly states the intent/condition of each function.

Comment: And this assumes the values to switch against are always `Number`s (for the first example)

Comment: @lan they are numbers in the original code. I see no problem - other than the order and he has the same problem with the dispatch table that I mentioned in Barmar's answer.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I understand, but this is a very generic question...note the `functionW`, `functionX`, etc. names. I can't expect the values to always be numbers. The fact that they're using a `switch` means they're doing an equality comparison, not with `<`, even if it satisfies the only example

Comment: Yea I suppose you're right. If you don't have ordinality in your cases you couldn't use this `if` structure.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I know I'm being real technical, I'm not trying to be annoying, I'm just trying to think of a generic answer

Comment: Your comment is valid, it's always good to look at the big picture :)

Comment: @Jacob Also, you shouldn't declare a variable as `function` - it' a reserved word, and will throw a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `switch`, consider iterating through a dispatch table:

```
var functions = [ functionW, functionX, functionY, functionZ ];
for (i = n; i < functions.length; i++) {
    functions[i]();
}
```

In this case, `n` should start with 0 rather than 1. And if `functionZ()` is really for all values higher than 3, you can cap `n` at the beginning of the loop:

```
for (i = (n >= functions.length ? functions.length-1 : n); i < functions.length; i++) {
```

Comment: I think you should not put `functionZ` in the dispatch table, call it after the `for` loop instead. It depends on possible values of `n` though, if `n` can be 5 this code is not equivalent.

Comment: You can cap `n` before the loop if necessary.

Comment: But you need to make sure `functionZ` _always_ gets called.

Answer (score 0):

I just thought of a different solution.

Write your functions like this:

```
function functionW() {
    // do stuff
    functionX();
}

function functionX() {
    // do stuff
    functionY();
}

// etc
```

Then you don't need a fallthrough, you can have one switch case *with* breaks.

Just because you defined your functions like `functionW`, `functionX` etc. *and* you need to call them in that way doesn't mean your function composition is necessarily *good*.