# Why does C++ require breaks in switch statements?

Tags: c++

When writing *switch* statements in C++, it seems necessary to include a *break* after every *case*. Otherwise, the code will continue to run into the next case.

For example:

```
int x = 1;
switch (x)
{
    case 0:
        std::cout << "x is 0." << std::endl;
    case 1:
        std::cout << "x is 1." << std::endl;
    case 2:
        std::cout << "x is 2." << std::endl;
    default:
        std::cout << "x is neither 0, 1 nor 2." << std::endl;
}
```

Will return:

```
>> x is 1.
>> x is 2.
```

However:

```
int x = 1;
switch (x)
{
    case 0:
        std::cout << "x is 0." << std::endl;
        break;
    case 1:
        std::cout << "x is 1." << std::endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        std::cout << "x is 2." << std::endl;
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "x is neither 0, 1 nor 2." << std::endl;
        break;
}
```

Will return:

```
>> x is 1.
```

My question is: If it is necessary to include the *break* for every *case*, then why does C++ require it to be explicitly written at all? Why not just *break* the *switch* statement after every *case* by default in C++? Are there any examples when this behaviour may not in fact be desired?

Comment: What would you do if you wanted the same output for different `case`'s?, this is something that would be a pain to handle if it wasn't for this behaviour

Comment: Because you may *want* to combine multiple cases

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: You could easily add something like explicit `continue` in that case.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188461/switch-statement-fallthrough-should-it-be-allowed

Comment: And that would be better? Not to mention, it would pollute the language with keywords that have very limited use.

Comment: It would be better, and `continue` is already a keyword...

Comment: @Puppy so is `break`. Why one instead of the other? How do you weigh them? Personal preference is not an appropriate guide here

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Because `break` is far more useful here than `continue`, so break-by-default is clearly the superior choice.

Comment: My guess is that when designing, the fall-through by default made it possible to conveniently assign the case action to different values.  However this forced everybody to put a break to end the case.  You could consider the break to be a separator, but in the end I find it a nuisance.

Comment: Other languages usually allow multiple items in the case more explicitly, i.e. case 0, 1, 2: .  I don't know how many bugs this construct in c++ is responsible for.  I'm going to stick my neck out and say it's quite a big number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is for the favour of "falling through" cases:

```
switch (x)
{
    case 0:
    case 1:
        std::cout << "x is 0 or 1." << std::endl;
        break;
}
```

In this example, the case statement is executed if x is either 0 or 1.

Comment: Even better, you can have some code in between `case 0` and `case 1` (e.g. do something specific to case 0, but then continue as like case 1 happened).

Comment: Did you intend that or is the missing break after case 0 a bug?  This is why I don't like the construct.

Comment: @Robinson that is the whole point, the `cout` gets executed for x=0 and x=1. No matter how it looks, it is still useful.

Comment: I know.  I'm just pointing out that a more explicit mechanism would improve the language and result in fewer bugs.

Comment: @Robinson I personally don't like the syntax of switch..case, too. But once you define a "standard", you can't change it so easily...

Comment: @keltar this is something extremely rare and hard-to-read. Lets admit that `switch` is just bad designed.

Comment: @Vassilis you're free to admit whatever you want. There are fallthrough attribute or even comments (which gcc understands) for that.

Answer (score 9):

It is because the `switch val` will be translated to a jump in assembly to specific address where `case (some value):` is, then the CPU will continue executing code as normal, so fetch next address and go on, fetch next and go on, the `case` blocks are in consecutive addresses in memory so the execution will fall through.
`break;` will tell the CPU to jump again, this time beyond the switch-case block not executing any more `case`es.

The fall through might be beneficiary, and in some newer languages You must explicitly say You want it, in C and C++ the fall through is implicit.

example from my machine:

```
int i=1;
switch (i) {
case 1:
        i=5;
        break;
default:
        i=6;
}
return 0;
```

will become

```
0x100000eeb:  movl   $0x1, -0x8(%rbp) ;int i=1;
0x100000ef2:  xorl   %eax, %eax
0x100000ef4:  movb   %al, %cl
0x100000ef6:  testb  %cl, %cl         ;switch(i)
0x100000ef8:  jne    0x100000f0f      ;i is not 1 go to default:
0x100000efe:  jmp    0x100000f03      ;i is 1 go to case 1:
0x100000f03:  movl   $0x5, -0x8(%rbp) ;case 1: i=5;
0x100000f0a:  jmp    0x100000f16      ;break;
0x100000f0f:  movl   $0x6, -0x8(%rbp) ;default: i=6;
0x100000f16:  movl   $0x0, %eax       ;first instruction after switch-case
```

if there were no jump after `i=5;` then the cpu would execute the `default:` as well.

Answer (score 4):

Because the behaviour was inherited from C, which uses explicit `break` instead. Switch fallthrough was much more useful then and that's why it was chosen as the "default" behaviour.

There was just a lot more programmer time and a lot less machine time so designing for maximum potential efficiency instead of readability made a lot more sense. And compilers had a lot less power to optimize (in many respects). You can look at things like Duff's Device for examples of how this behaviour was used.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a situation when you may require or want to get the same result for the two or may be more cases then you dont need a break. Something like this:

```
switch (x)
{
case 1:
case 2:
case 3:
 some task
 break;
deafult:
 do some other task
 break;
}
```

The above code is eventually the same as:

```
switch (x) {
    case 0: // The case 1 code is shared here
    case 1:
        // code
        goto case 2;
    case 2:
        //some code here
        goto default;
    default:
        //some other code
        break;
}
```

From the K&R

> Falling through from one case to another is not robust, being prone to
>   disintegration when the program is modified. With the exception of
>   multiple labels for a single computation, **fall-throughs should be used
>   sparingly, and commented.**
>
> **As a matter of good form, put a break after the last case** (the default
>   here) even though it's logically unnecessary. Some day when another
>   case gets added at the end, this bit of defensive programming will
>   save you.

As puppy has mentioned the bahaviour was inherent from the C language, so a quote from the book [Expert C Programming](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4vm2xK3yn34C&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=We%20analyzed%20the%20Sun%20C%20compiler%20sources%20to%20see%20how%20often%20the%20default%20fall%20through%20was%20used.%20The%20Sun%20ANSI%20C%20compiler%20front%20end%20has%20244%20switch%20statements,%20each%20of%20which%20has%20an%20average%20of&source=bl&ots=Hp61Sa_HfU&sig=xMRmcdUI6wYWqWXujZzYc87T7DQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OFs_VcSEPIbXarbsgfgI&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=We%20analyzed%20the%20Sun%20C%20compiler%20sources%20to%20see%20how%20often%20the%20default%20fall%20through%20was%20used.%20The%20Sun%20ANSI%20C%20compiler%20front%20end%20has%20244%20switch%20statements%2C%20each%20of%20which%20has%20an%20average%20of&f=false)

> We analyzed the Sun C compiler sources
>   to see how often the default fall
>   through was used.  The Sun ANSI C
>   compiler front end has 244 switch
>   statements, each of which has an
>   average of seven cases.  Fall through
>   occurs in just 3% of all these cases.
>
> In other words, the normal switch
>   behavior is *wrong* 97% of the time.
>   It's not just in a compiler - on the
>   contrary, where fall through was used
>   in this analysis it was often for
>   situations that occur more frequently
>   in a compiler than in other software,
>   for instance, when compiling operators
>   that can have either one or two
>   operands:
>
> ```
> switch (operator->num_of_operands) {
>     case 2: process_operand( operator->operand_2);
>               /* FALLTHRU */
>
>     case 1: process_operand( operator->operand_1);
>     break;
> }
> ```
>
> Case fall through is so widely
>   recognized as a defect that there's
>   even a special comment convention,
>   shown above, that tells lint "this is
>   really one of those 3% of cases where
>   fall through was desired."

Answer (score 1):

First of all the output of the first program looks like

```
x is 1.
x is 2.
x is neither 0, 1 nor 2.
```

C++ allows to pass the control through all case labels that has no break statement. For example

```
char c;

std::cin >> c;

switch ( c )
{
case 'y': 
case 'Y': 
    std::cout << "Y was pressed" << std::endl;
    break;

case 'n':
case 'N':
    std::cout << "N was pressed" << std::endl;
    break;

default:
    std::cout << "Neither Y nor N was pressed" << std::endl;
    break;
}
```

Some other languages as for example C# do not allow to do this. Nevertheless they require a break statement in any case.:)

Answer (score 1):

A very common example:

```
switch (month) {
 case 2:
   if(isLeapYear)
    days = 29;  
   else
    days = 28;
    break;
  case 4:
  case 6:
  case 9:    // do the same thing
  case 11:
    days = 30;
     break;
  default:
    days = 31;
 }
```

From the above example - you get a much cleaner code, and also, you have more flexibility than you would have if the switch required to break out implicitly after every case.

Comment: Although if the language specification had allowed `case 4, 6, 9, 11 :` it could have had a syntax for the above that avoided the undesirable default fall through behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is necessary to include a `break` or a `return` after every switch case.
An example where it is usefull, that not every case has an automatical break, is when you get key-events and certain keys should do the same thing:

```
switch (current_key) 
{
  case KEY_W:
  case KEY_UP:
  case KEY_SPACE:
       player->jump();
       break;
  case KEY_S:
  case KEY_DOWN:
  case KEY_SHIFT:
       player->cover();
       break;
  default:
       //Do something
       break; 
}
```

and you may write a function for you code like this:

```
const char* make_x_to_string(int x)
{
   switch (x)
   {
    case 0:
      return "x is zero";
    case 1:
      return "x is one";
    default:
      return "x is neither zero or one";
   }
}
```

and then simply call

```
cout << make_x_to_string(0) << endl;
```

You don't need `break` there, because `return` exits the function.