# C - Switch Statements - Difference in Output

Tags: c, switch-statement

I'm not really familiar with switch statements.

```
//S1
switch(ch) {
  case 'a': printf("eh? "); break;
  case 'e': printf("eee "); break;
  case 'i': printf("eye "); break;
  case 'o': printf("ohh "); break;
  case 'u': printf("you "); break;
}

//S2
switch(ch) {
  case 'a': printf("eh? ");
  case 'e': printf("eee ");
  case 'i': printf("eye ");
  case 'o': printf("ohh ");
  case 'u': printf("you ");
}
```

Is there a difference in outputs between these two chunks of code? And could you also please explain why?

Comment: Please insert the code directly in your question and not as an image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does C++ require breaks in switch statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915854/why-does-c-require-breaks-in-switch-statements)

Comment: Basically, you are asking what is 'break' operator is for in C language...

Comment: Why link? Try to write yourself. It will help you to understand "switch" statement

Comment: I'm in the process of typing out the code but having trouble with formatting - bear with me

Comment: @M.Ng googling the answer might be faster then typing...

Comment: Yeah I think I understand it now anyways, thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.

If the condition that matches the `switch` is in the topmost `case` statement, and you don't put a `break` (or `return`) in the end of it. It will fall through (execute all statements below it in the statemet).

For instance in the switch:

```
switch(ch) {
  case 'a': printf("eh? ");
  case 'e': printf("eee ");
  case 'i': printf("eye ");
  case 'o': printf("ohh ");
  case 'u': printf("you ");
}
```

if `ch` is equals to `i`, the printed output would be `eye ohh you`

Answer (score 1):

If in `switch case` statement there is no `break`, all statements after the first matching `case` will be executed. S2 does not have any `break` statements, therefore, if `ch = a`, S2 will execute all statements below it, printing 
`eh? eee eye ohh you`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a difference. In your first statement:

```
switch(ch) {
case 'a': printf("eh? "); break;
```

It will break here and only Print "eh? ". It won't execute second case 'e' part.

In your second statement:

```
switch(ch) {
  case 'a': printf("eh? ");
  case 'e': printf("eee ");
  case 'i': printf("eye ");
  case 'o': printf("ohh ");
  case 'u': printf("you ");
}
```

If you select case 'a', it will execute 'a' and every case after that because there is no break in this statement. It will print "eh? eee eye ohh you ".

If you select case 'i', it will execute case 'i' and every case after that printing "eye ohh you ".

One more thing I would like to suggest, take 'A' and 'a' both cases.
You can do that by:

```
switch(ch) {
  case 'a':case 'A': printf("eh? "); break;
  case 'e':case 'E': printf("eee "); break;
  case 'i':case 'I': printf("eye "); break;
  case 'o':case 'O': printf("ohh "); break;
  case 'u':case 'U': printf("you "); break;
  default: break;
}
```