# Why are these cases without statements ahead?

Tags: c, switch-statement

Into the following code `case 1:` to `case 2:` and `case 5:` seem to have no code for execution. My question is can't we just omit typing them?

```
switch(c)
{
  case 1:
  case 2:
  case 3:
    a++;
    break;
  case 5:
  default:
     b++;
  break;
}
```

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/188461/10077

Answer (score 5):

They fall through, i.e. if you encounter `1` or `2` it will jump into these cases and since there's no `break` just continue with case `3`. So you can not omit those, because otherwise `1` and `2` would jump to `default`.

Similarily, case `5` will fall through to `default`, meaning that you could omit `case 5`.

Essentially, `switch` statements can be imagined as `goto`-jumps to the appropriate positions. That means, that the program will jump into the appropriate case and continue working from there until it finds `break` or `return`. This means, that you have to write `break` or `return` explicitly if you don't want your program to continue execution in the subsequent `case`.

Answer (score 0):

> *My question is can't we just omit typing them?*

**TL;DR --** In your case, ***No***. They have some meaning.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.8.4.2, *The `switch` statement*

> The integer promotions are performed on the controlling expression. The constant expression in each case label is converted to the promoted type of the controlling expression. If a converted value matches that of the promoted controlling expression, control jumps to the statement following the matched `case` label....

That means, based on the *value* of `c` here, the particular "case" will be executed.

Fine. Wait, now we know where to take the control to **start** execution, but **where to stop, exactly?**

You're thinking *"before the next `case` body?"*

Well, not exactly. It does not automatically *stop* . Usually, we use a `break;` statement after each `case` block, to "mark" the end of that particular case. In case, the `break;` is not present, it will continue to execute the statements from following `case`s (if any), as if they are part of the same `case` block and it will continue until it reaches the end of `switch` body.

Now, to elaborate, in your case, if the value of `c` is either `1`, `2` or `3`, it will execute the statement block for `case 3`. Notice, there is no `break;` statement after `case 1:` and `case 2:` labels. It is kind of "fall-through" technique.

OTOH, if you remove the `case 1:` and `case 2:` labels, if `c` holds `1` or `2`, the control won't *reach* the block after `case 3:`, it will go to `default:` label.

However, `case 5:` will fall through to `default:` label, making it redundant. This once can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't omit them. Basically cases `1` and `2` will fallthrough to `3`. Omitting them would cause the default case to be executed for input values `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a fallthrough case. That means the cases fall down until a break appears. So `a++` would be excecuted with `c` being 1, 2, 3.

Answer (score 0):

The cases for 1,2 and 3 mean that if c=1,2 or 3 then a++. If c=5 or different then b++ - note that the code only stops if you hit a break so that c=1 gives the same as c=3 for example.

Answer (score 0):

They may be omitted but the result would be different.
Basically what the code does is for `c` equal to 1, 2, or 3 `a++` gets executed, otherwise, `b++` does.

In this case `case 5:` should be omitted after all as it will falls in the `default:` case.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed omit a case. This switch statement

```
switch(c)
{
  case 1:
  case 2:
  case 3:
    a++;
    break;
  case 5:
  default:
     b++;
  break;
}
```

can be rewritten like

```
switch(c)
{
  case 1:
  case 2:
  case 3:
    a++;
    break;
  default:
     b++;
  break;
}
```

without using label `case 5:` . But you may not exclude labels `case 1:` and `case 2:`

With these labels the switch statement can be rewritten using the if-else statement the following way

```
if ( 1 <= c && c <= 3 )
{
    a++;
}
else
{
    b++;
}
```

On the other hand without these case labels the corresponding if-else statement will look like

```
if ( c == 3 )
{
    a++;
}
else
{
    b++;
}
```

As you can see yourself there is a big difference between these two if-else statements.