# JavaScript switch strange behavior

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

I have following code snippets.

```
var caseObj = function () {

}

switch (typeof caseObj) {

    case "function":
        console.log("it is function");

    case "object":

        console.log("It is object now");
}
```

Its output is

```
it is function.
It is object now.
```

But `typeof caseObj` gives output `function` but it still evalutes 
**case "object"** case also.

How it is possible? Am I doing wrong anythig?

EDIT :

`typeof caseObj` is giving `function`,So it executing that case but it also 
 executing `object` case.Why this strange behavior?

Comment: use break between statements

Comment: Maybe relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188461/switch-statement-fallthrough-should-it-be-allowed

Comment: Forgot brakes (break)? :p

Comment: Add `break` at every case :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not with the `typeof`, but you've missed the `break` statement in the case. That'll make the `case` like **`function OR object`** and execute the block of both the cases.

You missed the [`break;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) statement for the `case`s. This is the reason, of falling out in the next `case`.

> The break statement terminates the current loop, switch, or label statement and transfers program control to the statement following the terminated statement.

```js
var caseObj = function() {

}

switch (typeof caseObj) {

  case "function":
    document.write("it is function");
    break;

  case "object":

    document.write("It is object now");
    break;
}
```

From the comments in the answer:

*But without break it also fall-down if there is not matching case and exit from switch.But it executing case "object": statment as well.Why?*

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#Description)

> If a match is found, the program executes the associated statements. If multiple cases match the provided value, the first case that matches is selected, even if the cases are not equal to each other.
>
> The optional break statement associated with each case label ensures that the program breaks out of switch once the matched statement is executed and continues execution at the statement following switch. If break is omitted, the program continues execution at the next statement in the switch statement.

Comment: Why there is need of break? typeof caseObj is "function" and not "object".Why it is evaluating last case also?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN `break` allows to get control out of the `switch`

Comment: without break it will keep evaluating the condition following the perticular case..

Comment: But without break it also fall-down if there is not matching case and exit from switch.But it executing  case "object": statment as well.Why?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN Because, parser thinks that the two cases are combined, since there is no `break` in between them

Comment: I ran into this issue with `switch` and found that if break is missing the other cases are executed even if they do not match. Seems completely absurd. Is there a logic behind this or its just a bug in the language ??

Answer (score 2):

The `switch` execution begins at the first `case` that matches the requested value, beginning from the top.

Then, unless you use a `break` somewhere, it will continue to execute all `case`s from the first that matches to the bottom.

As an example, if you invert your 2 `case`s in your example, it will only output "it is function".

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have a break statement ending each *case* clause. When you do this,  the control flow passes to the statements of the next *case* clause, not matter the *case* condition is not satisfied. For instance if you have:

```
var x = 1;
switch(x) {
   case 0: console.log(0);
   case 1: console.log(1);
   case 2: console.log(2);
   case 3: console.log(2);
}
```

The output would be:

```
1
2
3
```

but if you put the break in each case

```
var x = 1;
switch(x) {
   case 0: console.log(0);break;
   case 1: console.log(1);break;
   case 2: console.log(2);break;
   case 3: console.log(2);break;
}
```

the output would be just **1**