# Switch case jumps to wrong case in javascript (how to properly use the break command)

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

My code is not so long so I am pasting all of it here.

The code is not complete but when I run it it first jumps to case "start" which it is supposed to, and then jumps to case "end". I can see it because it prints both blocks' console log texts. Why is it jumping to the "end" case?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            function stepStream(stream,step){
                switch (stream[step]){
                    case "start":
                        console.log("Started reading stream...");
                    case "end":
                        var success = "Finished reading dataStream.";
                        console.log(success);
                        return success;
                    default:
                        throw "Data stream format is bad";                  
                    case "gesture":
                        console.log("Running case gesture! But why?");
                        step+=1;
                        stepStream(stream,step);
                    case "say":
                        step+=1;
                        stepStream(stream,step);
                    case "sleep":
                        step+=1;
                        stepStream(stream,step);
                }

            }

            var sentence1 = "Where are my bananas? I thought you put them in my bag?";
            var sentence2 = "This is a rather irritating situattion.";  
            var dataStream = ["start","gesture","banzai","sleep",1.0,"say",sentence1,
                                "say",sentence2,"gesture","kubikasige","end"];
            stepStream(dataStream,0);//Second parameter sets where to start reading the dataStream.


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need a `break` at the end of each `case` (except for the ones already ending with `return` or `throw`): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript switch strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369133/javascript-switch-strange-behavior)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are missing the `break` keyword after your `case` code. Without the break, subsequent blocks will be executed, that is why `end` is executed after `start` code. You can read more about this on [this W3Schools link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp).

Additionally, from the [JS reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch):

> The optional break statement associated with each case label ensures
>   that the program breaks out of switch once the matched statement is
>   executed and continues execution at the statement following switch. If
>   break is omitted, the program continues execution at the next
>   statement in the switch statement.

So your code should look like:

```
function stepStream(stream,step){
                switch (stream[step]){
                    case "start":
                        console.log("Started reading stream...");
                        break;
                    case "end":
                        var success = "Finished reading dataStream.";
                        console.log(success);
                        return success;
                    default:
                        throw "Data stream format is bad";                  
                    case "gesture":
                        //commUGesture(stream[i+1]);
                        //createLogLine("robot:CommU","event:gesture:"+stream[i+1]);
                        console.log("Running case gesture! But why?");
                        step+=1;
                        stepStream(stream,step);
                        break;
                    case "say":
                        step+=1;
                        stepStream(stream,step);
                        break;
                    case "sleep":
                        step+=1;
                        stepStream(stream,step);
                        break;
                }
```

Your "end" case has a return at the end, hence the code doesn't fall through to the other cases. Ideally, there should be a `break` at the end of each.

Comment: Ah, okay, got it, but why is it going to the "end" case when the only case I pass is "start"??

Comment: Because you do not have a break. It doesn't matter if case is matched after that or not. All the code till the next break (or return, throw) will be executed. I have added some more information in the answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, the switch function feels like a risky function to use though...

Comment: Not really, it becomes a habit to put break after every case the more you use it. Just like it becomes a habit to put semi colons or closing braces. I am sure you will find it useful :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a break statement in the start block, therefore it falls through to the end block.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is simple all `switch case` have to end with `break` or `return` statements in your case that is missing.

```
switch(var1)
{
    case "start":
        console.log("Started");
        break;
    case "end":
         console.log("stopped");
         return "";
     .
     .
     .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code will start running at the first matching "case", but it only stops running when it has reached a "break" or "return" statement;