# Hide ImageView hides multiple images

Tags: android

I'm trying to hide a specific die after it has been selected and used.
However, it keeps hiding all the `ImageView` below the one select

I've tried using different containers but can't seem to figure it out

This is XML for the dice for 3 of the dice:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img4"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:onClick="Select"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:srcCompat="?attr/colorControlHighlight" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:onClick="Select"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:srcCompat="?attr/colorControlHighlight" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:onClick="Select"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="?attr/colorControlHighlight" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
```

This is the method used to hide the dice:

```
public void RemoveDice(int pos) {
    switch (pos) {
        case 0:
            img1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        case 1:
            img2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        case 2:
            img3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        case 3:
            img4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        case 4:
            img5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        case 5:
            img6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        case 6:
            img7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        case 7:
            img8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        case 8:
            img9.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

This shows before selecting Blue 6
https://prnt.sc/peufqr
This after the selected die has been removed
https://prnt.sc/peugn7

I think my problem lies somewhere in the XML file but I am unsure what containers to use to prevent this.

Comment: You have to add break in every switch case

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `break` between each `case`. When using a `switch`, you have to add a `break`. Otherwise, it will execute any code until it reaches the end of the `switch` statement.

```
public void RemoveDice(int pos) {
    switch (pos) {
        case 0:
            img1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break; // Add this
        case 1:
            img2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break; // Add this
        case 2:
            img3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break; // Add this
        case 3:
            img4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break; // Add this
        case 4:
            img5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break; // Add this
        case 5:
            img6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break; // Add this
        case 6:
            img7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break; // Add this
        case 7:
            img8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break; // Add this
        case 8:
            img9.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break; // Add this
    }
}
```

Comment: worth noting (for OP) that a `switch` statement without a `break` is called a fall-through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188461/switch-statement-fallthrough-should-it-be-allowed

Comment: Thank you so much i feel really stupid now.... I did not even notice.

Answer (score 0):

You are not breaking switch case. use `break` statement

```
public void RemoveDice(int pos)
{
    switch (pos)
    {
        case 0:
            img1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
        case 1:
            img2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case 2:
            img3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case 3:
            img4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
        case 4:
            img5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case 5:
            img6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case 6:
            img7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case 7:
            img8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
        case 8:
            img9.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add breaks after every statement.

```
public void RemoveDice(int pos) {
    switch (pos) {
       case 0:
           img1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           break; // Add this
       case 1:
           img2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           break; // Add this
       case 2:
           img3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           break; // Add this
       case 3:
           img4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           break; // Add this
       case 4:
           img5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           break; // Add this
       case 5:
           img6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           break; // Add this
       case 6:
           img7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           break; // Add this
       case 7:
           img8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           break; // Add this
       case 8:
           img9.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           break; // Add this
   }
}
```