# Go to default case from another case in PHP

Tags: php, switch-statement

It is possible to go to `default` case from within some other case like this?

```
$a = 0;
$b = 4;
switch ($a) {
    case 0:
        if ($b == 5) {
            echo "case 0";
            break;
        }
        else
            //go to default
    case 1:
        echo "case 1";
        break;
    default:
        echo "default";
}
```

I tried to remove the `else` and was expecting that it would continue evaluating all following cases until `default` but it gets into `case 1` then. Why is it so and how can I get to the default one?

Comment: Personal suggestion: ditch the `switch` / `case` when it's not straightforward enough. Simply use an `if` / `else` instead: https://3v4l.org/OEkD6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can if you reorder the `case` statements:

```
switch ($a) {
    case 1:
        echo "case 1";
        break;
    case 0:
        if ($b == 5) {
            echo "case 0";
            break;
        }
    default:
        echo "default";
}
```

*Why is it so*:
it is defined, if you de not have a `break` statement the next `case` will be executed. If there is no more `case`, the `default` will be executed if one is defined

Comment: Is it not supposed to evaluate each case before executing it?

Comment: @yaugenka No it shouldn't

Comment: This answer is right - and it's what the original poster asked for - but it's generally accepted that it's not a good idea to use the 'fall through' feature of switch (that is, where you don't `break`, and just carry on into the next case) like this as it's highly unusual, and therefore very confusing to anyone who has read your code in the future.

Comment: Think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188461/switch-statement-fallthrough-should-it-be-allowed talks about this a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

You could re-order the case statements to allow a fall through to the next option, but if there are several times you wish to do this it can become impossible or just very fragile.  The alternative is to just more the common code into a function...

```
function defaultCase()  {
     echo "default";
}

switch ($a) {
    case 0:
        if ($b == 5) {
            echo "case 0";
        }
        else {
            defaultCase();
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        echo "case 1";
        break;
    default:
       defaultCase();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a simple `if` / `else` as I mentioned in the comments.

However, here's another way you could do it using a `switch` statement, if that helps:

```
switch ([$a, $b]) {
  case [0, 5]:
    echo 'case 0';
    break;
  case [1, $b]:
    echo 'case 1';
    break;
  default:
    echo 'default';
}
```