# Switch-case typescript case not working on string

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following switch simple case:

```
let ca: string = "2";

switch (ca) {
case "2":
    console.log("2");

 case "1":
    console.log("1");

default:
    console.log("default");
```

}

I'm trying to understand why the output of this code is:

```
2
1
default
```

My expected output is

`2 
default`

why its print

`1`

even if ca isn't equal "1"?

**EDIT:** I know that I can add `break` statment - I just trying to understand why `case "1"` occurred if `ca="2"`

Thanks.

Comment: Useful reading that will clear some of your confusion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188461/switch-statement-fallthrough-should-it-be-allowed

Answer (score 23):

You need to add a `break` statement in each of the `case` you have for the switch block otherwise it will keep executing further once the match is found.

```
let ca: string = "2";

switch (ca) {
  case "2":
    console.log("2");
    break;

  case "1":
    console.log("1");
    break;

  default:
    console.log("default");
}
```

Comment: I know that,  I'm trying to  understand why case "1" occured even in ca="2"

Comment: @samisaviv that's how `switch` works. It starts with the specific `case` and runs all the cases below it if you don't add `break`. If you set `ca = "1"`, it runs `case "1"` AND `default`

Comment: If your question is why was ``switch`` with falls through strategy, I guess it is to give the possibility to make an "OR" with the switch e.g.
```
switch (ca) {
  case "2":
  case "1":
    console.log("smaller than 3");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `switch` statement in JavaScript [falls through](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) to the next case until a `break` statement is hit:

> The switch statement evaluates an expression, matching the expression's value to a case clause, and executes statements associated with that case, **as well as statements in cases that follow the matching case**.

TypeScript is no different in this regard. It's an unfortunate holdover from the C language, or maybe even older.

I recommend you enable the compiler option `--noFallthroughCasesInSwitch` so the compiler will prevent the common mistake of  forgetting the `break` statement.

Comment: Manipulating the compiler isn't a solution to misunderstanding a fundamental.

Comment: Indeed it's not, but I believe I addressed the misunderstanding as well. The last sentence was just me trying to be helpful for OP and future readers.