# Break inside case brackets in a switch statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement, break, brackets

I'm curious about inserting the break inside a brackets in a case.

```
  int a = 1;
    switch (a)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        a = a;
        break;
    }
    a = a;
    case 2:
    {
        a = a;
        
    }
    break;
    }
```

In the C++ code above, in case 1 I've inserted the break inside the brackets, it is an error?

Is there any difference between case 1 and case 2 in the example above?

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188461/switch-statement-fall-through-should-it-be-allowed

Comment: Regarding the "is it an error" question, that can be very simply answered by trying it. If you build with extra warnings enabled, the compiler will definitely be able to tell you if it's syntactically correct or not, and very likely if there's any other possible problems.

Comment: Your C++ textbook should have an explanation, in one of its introductory chapters, how the `break` statement works, which should answer this question. Is there something ***specific*** in the explanation that's unclear?

Comment: You can also write `if (1 == 2) cout << "x";` it's obviously wrong but it's not a c++ error. The compiler will warn about this, usually at level 4 warning.

Answer (score 4):

> *Is there any difference between case 1 and case 2 in the example above?*

In terms of the execution of the code and the behaviour of the `break` statement – no. [From this Draft C++17 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf):

> ##### 9.6.1 The break statement        [stmt.break]
>
> <sup>1</sup>    The break statement
> shall occur only in an iteration-statement or a `switch` statement and
> causes termination of the smallest enclosing iteration-statement or
> `switch` statement; control passes to the statement following the
> terminated statement, if any.

So, any 'extra' enclosing scopes (blocks delimited by `{ ... }`) are irrelevant: the `break` will operate on the first `switch` (or iteration statement) the compiler finds in an 'outward search' from where it is placed. (Note that the same is true for a `break` statement inside the scope of an `if` block: that will still break out of the enclosing `switch` block or `while`/`for` loop.)