# C# switch variable initialization: Why does this code NOT cause a compiler error or a runtime error?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

```
...
case 1:
   string x = "SomeString";
   ...
   break;
case 2:
   x = "SomeOtherString";
   ...
   break;
...
```

Is there something that I am not understanding about the switch statement in C#? Why would this not be an error when case 2 is used?

Edit: This code works and doesn't throw an error.

Comment: you just need to put string x = "SomeOtherString";

then it will work. the, you can not use case 1 variable in case 2. out of scope error will occur.

Comment: make sure case 2 require code modification.

Comment: @Syed - that is not correct. NO error occurs with this code.

Comment: that is because you already defined string x, out side the switch statement, therefore you are not getting any error.
that string x is acting global in case 2.

Let me know.

Comment: @Syed - Your comments have been incorrect. x is ONLY defined in case 1 in my code.

Comment: (OK then, a comment)

It's not an error because the program obeys the rules of C# as described in our published specification. Why do you believe that this fragment should be an error?  What part of the specification do you believe has been violated?

Comment: @eric-lippert and @JCron: just wrrap case 1 with braces, then he will definitely get compile time error.

Comment: @eric - I assumed that case 2 was in a different scope than case 1. It seemed logical that when defining a variable inside a case statement, that it wouldn't be available outside of that case statement.

Comment: Though that is the case for many textual regions -- for example, the statement portion of a for, foreach, using, switch, and so on -- it is explicitly not true of a switch section. The specification carefully defines "scope" and describes what regions introduce scope boundaries. See the spec if you want the details.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to be careful how you think about the `switch` statement here. There's *no creation of variable scopes* going on at all, in fact. Don't let the fact that just because the code within cases gets indented that it resides within a child scope.

When a switch block gets compiled, the `case` labels are simply converted into labels, and the appropiate `goto` instruction is executed at the start of the switch statement depending on the switching expression. Indeed, you can manually use `goto` statements to create "fall-through" situations (which C# does directly support), as [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(VS.71).aspx) suggests.

```
goto case 1;
```

If you specifically wanted to create scopes for each case within the `switch` block, you could do the following.

```
...
case 1:
{
   string x = "SomeString";
   ...
   break;
}
case 2:
{
   string x = "SomeOtherString";
   ...
   break;
}
...
```

This *requires* you to redeclare the variable `x` (else you will receive a compiler error). The method of scoping each (or at least some) can be quite useful in certain situations, and you will certainly see it in code from time to time.

Comment: @Syed: Yeah, I meant to point out that for the scoped switch block the compiler *would* generate an error. I've clarified that to show that you need to redefine x in this case.

Comment: @Noldorin: Another thing I want to let you know, that his code was not getting any error in case 2. That is because he already defined string x before switch. That become global and case 2 always execute without any error.

Comment: @Syed - you are incorrect - I DID NOT define x outside of the switch.

Comment: @JCron: If anything is bad, that came from my side. If anything good, that is because of Creator.
Be cool and accept my humble apology.

Answer (score 8):

The documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132.aspx) says :

> The scope of a local variable declared in a switch-block of a switch statement (Section 8.7.2) is the switch-block.

Also, a similar question has been asked before:
[Variable declaration in c# switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222601/variable-declaration-in-c-switch-statement)

Comment: Thank you - I did not find the other question.

Answer (score 4):

There is no compiler error because the switch statement does not create a new scope for variables.

If you declare a variable inside of a switch, the variable is in the same scope as the code block surrounding the switch.  To change this behavior, you would need to add {}:

```
...
case 1:
    // Start a new variable scope 
    {
        string x = "SomeString";
        ...
    }
    break;
case 2:
    {
        x = "SomeOtherString";
        ...
    }
    break;
...
```

This will cause the compiler to complain.  However, switch, on it's own, doesn't internally do this, so there is no error in your code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the scoping of variables is within the switch, not the case, probably because cases can be stacked. Notice if you try to reference x outside of the switch it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

if are creating any local variable within case, you can not use them out side case.

```
...
int opt ;
switch(opt)
{
case 1:
{
   string x = "SomeString";
   ...
}
   break;
case 2:
{
   string x = "SomeOtherString";
   ...
}
   break;
default:
{
//your code
}
break;
}
...
```

Comment: if you case contain multiple statements, then put {your multiple statements in brackets} and outside put break;

Comment: see case 2, you did not declare string X, but in my case 2, it is properly definded

Comment: whoever give vote down, please specify reason, so I know what is wrong with my reply..

Comment: @JCron, if your code is correct, then why you are here on SO.
My dear friend, we are here to helping you out.

Comment: most probably, you already defined string x, out side the switch statement, therefore you are not getting any error.

Comment: @Syed - Please read the question that I asked. I didn't ask 'Why is my correct code correct?' I didn't understand some code that I came across and wanted to. Something that I think is a perfectly reasonable question to ask.

Comment: @Syed - I don't understand why you don't understand that I didn't declare string x outside of the switch. read the accepted answer.

Comment: @JCron: My dear frind, you are still not reading accepted answer carefully, he also mentioned that you need to re-declare x in your scope.

Comment: @Syed - you aren't understanding the question OR the answer. If the braces are used, x needs redefined, else the code compiles and works as I have it in my question. Don't believe me? Try it out before posting any more incorrect comments.

Comment: just a quick comment: if you dont use braces, then cases become ambiguous and act weird.

Answer (score -2):

move the string declaration to before the

```
switch(value)
```

statement. Then assign x for each case.

Comment: He's not asking HOW to get it to work... but why there is no compiler error.