# Why does C# allow statements after a case but not before it?

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement

Why does C# allow *this*:

```
var s = "Nice";
switch (s)
{
    case "HI":
        break;
    const string x = "Nice";
    case x:
        Console.Write("Y");
        break;
}
```

But not *this*:

```
var s = "Nice";
switch (s)
{
    const string x = "Nice";
    case x:
        Console.Write("Y");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Any other language allows it?

Comment: why would you want to do either?

Comment: Whether or not it's likely someone would write code like this, it's still an interesting question. There must be some strange scoping stuff going on behind the scenes.

Comment: @Jodrell: Was trying to understand how switch scopes work. I had a variable declared inside a case statement and it was saying it was already declared in another case statement. Then I tried to move it outside the case statement, and I landed here.

Comment: @StealthRabbi not really, its just illegal to have other statements between `switch` and the first `case`. The second block works because `const` statements are not executed at runtime anyway.

Comment: I really wonder why you'd want to do `const string x = "Nice"; case x:`, when you can do `case "Nice":` just as well. Not only is it less code, it's also easier to read and doesn't even impact performance in a negative way.

Comment: Interesting enough, Visual Studio said that only constant are allowed in case statements, I just moved on to try a constant. I don't get that either.

Comment: @rtuner The reason the case statements need to be compile time constants is because the implementation of `switch` is a dictionary, not a series of `if/else if` statements.  It needs them to result in an object which can be the key of the dictionary.  It's also important that there be no side effects of evaluating the case since those side effects wouldn't be generated when testing the cases as they would be in, say, C++.

Comment: I always thought it odd that you don't need to put curly braces around your code when you have more than one statement after a case. It kind of makes switch statements feel more like a goto than an if.

Comment: @MartinBrown That's because they more or less are (logically, not in implementation; in implementation it's a dictionary, as I said), and also because there isn't actually an inner scope for each `case` statement, unless you use braces.  This compiles and runs fine: `case "a": string a = ""; break; case "b": string b = a;break;`.

Comment: Scrub my previous assertion about the scoping rules of `const` http://www.jaggersoft.com/csharp_standard/15.5.2.htm, However, a `switch` is a scoping block and a `case` is not, so a variable declared in an earlier `case` of the same switch is still in scope. The perculair thing about `const` is, it doesn't have to be reachable to be valid. That makes sense because they are not executed at runtime. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074589/case-statement-block-level-declaration-space-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks for posting this question; I'm going to add this one to my list of switch oddities and my list of subtle Mono errors. If you're interested in unusual uses of the switch statement see my article on that subject: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/13/four-switch-oddities.aspx

Comment: What da??? Thanks for that post @EricLippert. Learnt a lot of new stuff. Thanks

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Because your indentation is misleading, the first code actually is:

```
var s = "Nice";
switch (s)
{
    case "HI":
        break;
        const string x = "Nice";
    case x:
        Console.Write("Y");
        break;
}
```

That is, `x` is declared inside a `case` statement (though after a `break`), where it is valid. However, directly inside a `switch` statement it’s invalid – the only valid statements there are `case` and `default`.

Furthermore, `const` declarations are evaluated *at compile time*, so `x` is defined even though there’s a `break` statement before.

However, note that the Mono C# compiler **will not compile** this code, it complains that “the name ‘`x`’ does not exist in the current scope” so Mono seems to implement more checks than the .NET compiler. However, I can’t find any rules in the C# standard which forbid this use of the `const` declaration so I assume that the .NET compiler is right and the Mono compiler is wrong.

Comment: But how come it displays y, if it does actually break?

Comment: @rtuner I guess because the `const` declaration is moved to the top of the method at compile time.

Comment: @rtuner `const` statements are not executed at runtime, they are substituted at compile time. Try and put a break point on it.

Comment: @rtuner because it's a constant, it's assignment is done statically, no when it arrives at that line.

Comment: But _why_ is any code allowed after the break and before the next case?

Comment: @Magnus because it will lead to "unreachable" code, which is not invalid at that location.

Comment: @Magnus Why are you allowed to put code after a `return;` and before the end of that scope?  It's code that won't run.  The answer is simply because they didn't bother to make it illegal; making it illegal was more work than just leaving it, and leaving it doesn't really cause problems.  The feature request to prohibit it just isn't worth the effort to implement.

Comment: The problem I have with this answer is that: `case HI": break; string x = "Nice";` is invalid, so I don't think you're correct Magnus.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata The only reason that's illegal is because with that change the second case wouldn't evaluate to a compile time constant.  If you don't use `x` in the second case then the code compiles just fine, even with that change.  That shows that this answer *is* right.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata Is it invalid? The Mono compiler compiles it and nothing in the standard forbids it. If the .NET C# compiler rejects it, report a bug.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I compiled it; it compiles fine.

Comment: Hmmmm? you compiled `case HI": break; string x = "Nice";`??? I am saying the answer is a bit misleading since you tend to think it's valid to write something after break, but it's not.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata The implementation is that a case statement can be followed by any number of statements.  It actually does do a reachability check, and it will generate a warning saying that the given line is unreachable, but it doesn't go out of it's way to generate an error even though it detects unreachable code.  Why should they spend extra time and effort to change that warning into an error?  What does it gain?  If you can justify that, then go ahead and propose it to Microsoft.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata In what way is it not valid?

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata [Yes, it compiles](http://ideone.com/Ofb1CW) (add the missing quote though: `case "HI"`)

Comment: Seems, you're all getting this wrong, `case "HI": break; string x = "Nice"; case x: Console.Write("Y"); break;` doesn't compile.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata Correct, for reasons that [I've already explained to you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694189/why-does-c-sharp-allow-statements-after-a-case-but-not-before-it#comment24027050_16694227).  It has nothing to do with the fact that it's unrechable; it's because `case` statements must be compile time constants.  If you change the second case to `case "bye":break;` then it compiles just fine.

Comment: To address your last paragraph: indeed, Mono appears to be in the wrong here. But one can hardly blame them; this is a bizarre scenario. I wonder if Mono gets other rules about scoping inside switch statements wrong? I shall find out!

Comment: I agree with @Eric Lippert--Mono appears to be wrong. Also, I'm surprised that the compiler didn't at least issue a warning about unreachable code--but, since it's a `const` that's being defined, which as someone else mentioned gets replaced at compile-time with its defined value, then that statement probably just gets eliminated and you simply end up with `case "Hi": break; case "Nice" /* Substituted for 'x' by the compiler */: ...`.

Comment: @fourpastmidnight: Right, there's nothing executable there to be unreachable, so the warning is suppressed.

Answer (score 7):

Because the language specification does not allow a const directly in your switch (only case and default are allowed):

```
switch (expression)
{
   case constant-expression:
      statement
      jump-statement
   [default:
      statement
      jump-statement]
}
```

Where:

> **`expression:`** An integral or string type expression.
>   **`statement:`** The embedded statement(s) to be executed if control is transferred to the case or the default.
>   **`jump-statement:`** A jump statement that transfers control out of the case body.
>   **`constant-expression:`** Control is transferred to a specific case according to the value of this expression.

In the first case the const is part of your case logic. The const will is only working because it is rewritten at compiletime and not at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

... because `switch` does this

```
jump_to_the_label_matchig(s)
{
   label1:
      ...
      done_quit_this;
   label2:
      ...
      done_quit_this;
   d'oh:
      ...
      done_quit_this;
}
```

and not this

```
now_jump_to_the_label_matchig(s)
{

   le'mme_wander_around_doing_things_that_could_have_been_done_before_me;

   label1:
      ...
      done_quit_this;
   label2:
      ...
```

I betcha that if that was allowed, you'd find people willing to do all their programming in there :-)