# Scope of locals in switch statement

Tags: c#

I was surprised to discover that locals in switch statements are scoped to the switch statement and not to the case. Why is that? And is it good practice to add curly braces around each case as a workaround.

This won't compile:

```
switch (n)
{
    case 1:
       var i = 1;
       Console.WriteLine(i);
       break;
    default:
       var i = 2;
       Console.WriteLine(i);
       break;
}
```

This does compile:

```
switch (n)
{
    case 1:
    {
       var i = 1;
       Console.WriteLine(i);
       break;
    }
    default:
    {
       var i = 2;
       Console.WriteLine(i);
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is that? Because that's the way the language was designed.

Comment: scope is a code between `{...}` e.g. `if (1 == 1) var i = 15; else var i = 20;` will produce the same problem. In *time of old* (`C`, early `C++`) `case`s was just a *computable* `label` (`switch` computed value and made a `goto` to label found)

Comment: A duplicate with a better answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1074589

Comment: @Henk Added that to the dupes list.

Comment: `And is it good practice to add curly braces around each case as a workaround` Well, this is of course only my opinion, but I think that it is perfectly acceptable to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This is a design choice specifically made by C#.

A variable only exists inside the innermost braces in which the variable is first declared. This makes it easy to check the variables scope just by looking, and I might guess it also makes parsing easier

Comment: ... with some exceptions: consider closures.