# How can this variable in a switch statement be used seemingly without being declared?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, variable-initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# switch variable initialization: Why does this code NOT cause a compiler error or a runtime error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864153/c-sharp-switch-variable-initialization-why-does-this-code-not-cause-a-compiler)

In this switch statement (which to my surprise compiles and executes without error), the variable something is not declared in case 2, and case 1 never executes. How is this valid? How can the variable something be used without being declared?

```
switch(2){
 case 1:
  string something = "whatever";
  break;
 case 2:
  something = "where??";
  break;
}
```

Comment: Okay, when you output 'something', what does the console tell you? Actually 'where'? Regarding the 'why this works': I can only wager, that when you create a variable in the 'same block' (like the switch statement), it creates the variable, no matter if the actual code is ever reached or not.

Comment: @ATaylor - No, `something`'s scope is limited to the `switch`.

Comment: See the accepted answer of this question:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864153/c-sharp-switch-variable-initialization-why-does-this-code-not-cause-a-compiler][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864153/c-sharp-switch-variable-initialization-why-does-this-code-not-cause-a-compiler

Comment: "How can something be used without being initialized?" Note that *that* is not what's happening here. You might read it as using an *undeclared* variable (although that is *also* not the case), but nowhere are you using an unitiliazed variable, that is a separate concept. Indeed, the only usages are assignments.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram - You contradict yourself in those last 2 sentences. An assignment is a use. However, your point about initialization versus declaration is valid and I edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because a `switch` statement is scoped across cases. Therefore, when the `switch` statement is originally processed it defines a variable named `something` and would have its default value ... in this case `null`.

And to be more precise, when the IL is generated, a variable is available in scope for any `case` at or below its definition. So, if a variable is declared in the second `case` it's not available in the first `case` but would be available in the third `case`.

Comment: is that done by the compiler?

Comment: @TravisJ, yes. I edited the question to clarify that.

Comment: "the variables defined in any case inside the switch are defined at the top of the scope" that is not entirely the case. If `something` is declared in case 2 instead of case 1, then there is an error.

Comment: @TravisJ, my apologies, let me modify the statement. Thanks!