# Why are different case condition bodies not in different scope?

Tags: java, switch-statement

Why are different case bodies not automatically in their own scope?  For example, if I were to do this:

```
switch(condition) {
  case CONDITION_ONE:
    int account = 27373;
  case CONDITION_TWO:
    // account var not needed here
  case CONDITION_THREE:
    // account var not needed here
  case CONDITION_FOUR:
    int account = 90384;
}
```

the compiler would complain about local variable redefinitions.  I understand I could do this:

```
switch(condition) {
  case CONDITION_ONE: {
    int account = 27373;
  }
  case CONDITION_TWO: {
    // account var not needed here
  }
  case CONDITION_THREE: {
    // account var not needed here
  }
  case CONDITION_FOUR: {
    int account = 90384;
  }
}
```

to put a block around each set of statements to be executed to put each `account` variable in its own scope.  But why doesn't the language do this for me?

Why would you ever want to declare a local variable in `CONDITION_ONE`'s body and then use it in `CONDITION_TWO`'s?  This seems like a TERRIBLE idea which should be explicitly banned, not implicitly permitted.

Comment: **Because [he](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Gosling "James Gosling") said so!!** *(My new favorite answer)*

Comment: That's a damned good question; I encountered exactly the same frustration yesterday.

Comment: More bluntly: Why would you ever want to declare a local variable in a switch? Use them sparingly; putting control logic in a case is a recipe for a confusing program!

Comment: because it is really "goto" in disguise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be inconsistent with the rest of the language.

As it is, scope is *always* determined by blocks. That sort of consistency makes Java easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 6):

Why would you *want* this? If you need a new scope for each case block, you're doing too much in your case block. Push that off to a method.

Comment: Highly agree, and even if you *did* want to do too much in a case block, you still wouldn't need separate scopes.  Remember the whole reason scope was invented was so `account` in one block is different than `account` in the other, which is not a concern when the scopes never overlap.

Answer (score 4):

Because that is how C works and Java was designed to lure C programmers over.

Comment: Because the Unix-folks at Bell Labs needed a portable assembler, and the switch statement without blocks mapped very well to their target machine code output.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other answers, you would also lose the benefits of fallthrough should a subsequent case need to be in the same scope as the previous one. As far as I know, its much easier to add a new level of scope than try to escape one forced upon you by the language.

Answer (score 2):

I'm happy that it exactly like that. The scope of a [local variable *is always* a block](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.12.3). One single rule, no exceptions.

**One Block to rule them all, One Block to find them,

One Block to bring them all and in the darkness bind them**

Comment: Actually I prefer linkers to be _light_.

Answer (score 1):

Lucky enough for you, you're in a good company in not liking this behavior - [Jon Skeet agrees with you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222601/variable-declaration-in-c-switch-statement/222614#222614) :)

Yes, I know the link is to a question about C, but this Java behavior is inherited from C's block scoping rules.

Answer (score 0):

Because, you may want to do this:

```
switch(condition) {
  case CONDITION_ONE:
    int account = 27373;
  case CONDITION_TWO:
    DoStuffHere();
  case CONDITION_THREE:
  case CONDITION_FOUR:
    DoMoreStuffHere();
}
```

then, and with this... if you got "CONDITION_ONE", then the variable would be set, and both DoStuffHere and DoMoreStuffHere would be called. But, if otherwise you got CONDITION_THREE, then, only DoMoreStuffHere would be called.

Comment: How, exactly, is that relevant to scoping?

Comment: Well, he could use the "account" in any of the "cases".

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as others have said - more or less - because that is the way things work.

Perhaps Tom Tresansky really meant how to achieve the desired effect.

```
switch(condition) {
  case CONDITION_ONE:
    { int account = 27373; }
  case CONDITION_TWO:
    // account var not needed here
  case CONDITION_THREE:
    // account var not needed here
  case CONDITION_FOUR:
    { int account = 90384; }
}
```