# How to cast a string to any type where the type info is stored in the form of "System.Int32", "System.Color", etc?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, casting

I have some values in an xml file:

```
...
<Effect>
  <Type>Blur</Type>
  <Options>
    <Option Type="System.Int32">88</Option>
    <Option Type="System.Drawing.Color">Color [A=0, R=1, G=2, B=3]</Option>
  </Options>
</Effect>
...
```

So when I get `effect.Options[0]`, it comes as a string `"88"`. I want to cast it to `"System.Int32"`. Same with `effect.Options[1]` where I want to cast it to `"System.Drawing.Color"`.

Something like:

```
Converter.Convert value<object> "type"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't married to your example XML format, look into [XmlSerialization](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813).  All those details are taken care of for you on serialization and deserialization - in only a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

For Colors:

```
System.Drawing.ColorConverter colConvert = new ColorConverter();
Color c =  (System.Drawing.Color)colConvert.ConvertFromString("#FF00EE");
```

though I'm not sure what kind of arguments ConvertFromString takes...

---

Something like:

```
    string sType = "System.Int32";//Get your type from attribute 
    string value = "88"; //Get your element 

    switch (sType)
    {
        case "System.Int32":
            int i = (int)Convert.ChangeType(value, Type.GetType("System.Int32"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            break;
        case "System.Drawing.Color" :
            Color c = (Color)Convert.ChangeType(value, Type.GetType("System.Drawing.Color"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            break;
    }
```

**OR**

```
for (int i = 0; i < effect.Options.Count; i++)
{
    object oResult = Convert.ChangeType(effect.Options[i], Type.GetType(effect.Options[i].Attributes["Type"].Value.ToString()), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    if (oResult is int)
    {
        //Process as int
        int iTmp = (int)oResult;
    }
    else if (oResult is Color)
    {
        //process as color
        Color cTmp = (Color)oResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Convert.ChangeType` doesn't work to convert to a color. It throws "Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Drawing.Color'."

Answer (score -1):

<strike>switch(Type.GetType(effect.Options[0].ToString()))
    {
        case typeOf(System.Int32):
            int i = (System.Int32)effect.Options[0];
            break;
        case typeOf(System.Drawing.Color):
            System.Drawing.Color color = (System.Drawing.Color)effect.Options[0];
            break;
    }</strike>

```
if(effect.Options[0].Attributes["Type"].Value.ToString()) == "System.Int32" /*pseudo code here in this part, just showing that you need to get the type from the XML as an attribute or whatever*/)
{
    int i = (System.Int32)effect.Options[0];
}
else if(effect.Options[0].Attributes["Type"].Value.ToString()) == "System.Drawing.Color"/*pseudo code here in this part, just showing that you need to get the type from the XML as an attribute or whatever*/)
{
    System.Drawing.Color color = (System.Drawing.Color)effect.Options[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in this case the case statements will use string values? How did you get those from strings? Also do I have to use switch for this? Just wondering. Last thing, can you cast a color string to Color, like that? Would it work?

Comment: It will not work. C# doesn't support switch statement with types.

Comment: Still won't work. You can't just add a cast and expect the conversion to magically work.

Comment: Neat, didn't know that about the switch statement. I learn something every day. Here it is with if statements instead. @Etienne: Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Yeah, he might have to get the type from the XML, not a GetType huh?

Comment: Can someone point me to somewhere that says you can't use types with switch statements? I don't see it anywhere. And this question doesn't mention it at all . . . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222601/variable-declaration-in-c-switch-statement

Comment: Sorry man, I was looking on the net, I couldn't find anywhere and msdn seems to be down. I am sure someone will post a link.