# Is there an easy way to convert a number to a word in PHP?

Tags: php, numbers

In PHP, is there an easy way to convert a number to a word? For instance, *27* to *twenty-seven*.

Comment: There's no built-in way that I'm aware of, but if you have a look at my example code for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174155/switch-statement-fallthrough-in-c) (in C#) it should be easy enough for you to get working. Basically it'd just be a matter of untyping the variables and adding the `$` prefix where appropriate and it should work.

Comment: I found two links for this. The [first](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/3289.html) is a freeware PHP class you could use, the [second](http://marc.info/?l=php-general&m=99928281523866&w=2) is a example function you could have a look at and copy or use to write your own.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I [found](http://bloople.net/num2text/cnumlib.txt) some (2007/2008) source-code online and as it is copyright but I can use it freely and modify it however I want, so I place it here and re-license under CC-Wiki:

```
<?php
/**
 * English Number Converter - Collection of PHP functions to convert a number
 *                            into English text.
 *
 * This exact code is licensed under CC-Wiki on Stackoverflow.
 * http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
 *
 * @link     http://stackoverflow.com/q/277569/367456
 * @question Is there an easy way to convert a number to a word in PHP?
 *
 * This file incorporates work covered by the following copyright and
 * permission notice:
 *
 *   Copyright 2007-2008 Brenton Fletcher. http://bloople.net/num2text
 *   You can use this freely and modify it however you want.
 */

function convertNumber($number)
{
    list($integer, $fraction) = explode(".", (string) $number);

    $output = "";

    if ($integer{0} == "-")
    {
        $output = "negative ";
        $integer    = ltrim($integer, "-");
    }
    else if ($integer{0} == "+")
    {
        $output = "positive ";
        $integer    = ltrim($integer, "+");
    }

    if ($integer{0} == "0")
    {
        $output .= "zero";
    }
    else
    {
        $integer = str_pad($integer, 36, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $group   = rtrim(chunk_split($integer, 3, " "), " ");
        $groups  = explode(" ", $group);

        $groups2 = array();
        foreach ($groups as $g)
        {
            $groups2[] = convertThreeDigit($g{0}, $g{1}, $g{2});
        }

        for ($z = 0; $z < count($groups2); $z++)
        {
            if ($groups2[$z] != "")
            {
                $output .= $groups2[$z] . convertGroup(11 - $z) . (
                        $z < 11
                        && !array_search('', array_slice($groups2, $z + 1, -1))
                        && $groups2[11] != ''
                        && $groups[11]{0} == '0'
                            ? " and "
                            : ", "
                    );
            }
        }

        $output = rtrim($output, ", ");
    }

    if ($fraction > 0)
    {
        $output .= " point";
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($fraction); $i++)
        {
            $output .= " " . convertDigit($fraction{$i});
        }
    }

    return $output;
}

function convertGroup($index)
{
    switch ($index)
    {
        case 11:
            return " decillion";
        case 10:
            return " nonillion";
        case 9:
            return " octillion";
        case 8:
            return " septillion";
        case 7:
            return " sextillion";
        case 6:
            return " quintrillion";
        case 5:
            return " quadrillion";
        case 4:
            return " trillion";
        case 3:
            return " billion";
        case 2:
            return " million";
        case 1:
            return " thousand";
        case 0:
            return "";
    }
}

function convertThreeDigit($digit1, $digit2, $digit3)
{
    $buffer = "";

    if ($digit1 == "0" && $digit2 == "0" && $digit3 == "0")
    {
        return "";
    }

    if ($digit1 != "0")
    {
        $buffer .= convertDigit($digit1) . " hundred";
        if ($digit2 != "0" || $digit3 != "0")
        {
            $buffer .= " and ";
        }
    }

    if ($digit2 != "0")
    {
        $buffer .= convertTwoDigit($digit2, $digit3);
    }
    else if ($digit3 != "0")
    {
        $buffer .= convertDigit($digit3);
    }

    return $buffer;
}

function convertTwoDigit($digit1, $digit2)
{
    if ($digit2 == "0")
    {
        switch ($digit1)
        {
            case "1":
                return "ten";
            case "2":
                return "twenty";
            case "3":
                return "thirty";
            case "4":
                return "forty";
            case "5":
                return "fifty";
            case "6":
                return "sixty";
            case "7":
                return "seventy";
            case "8":
                return "eighty";
            case "9":
                return "ninety";
        }
    } else if ($digit1 == "1")
    {
        switch ($digit2)
        {
            case "1":
                return "eleven";
            case "2":
                return "twelve";
            case "3":
                return "thirteen";
            case "4":
                return "fourteen";
            case "5":
                return "fifteen";
            case "6":
                return "sixteen";
            case "7":
                return "seventeen";
            case "8":
                return "eighteen";
            case "9":
                return "nineteen";
        }
    } else
    {
        $temp = convertDigit($digit2);
        switch ($digit1)
        {
            case "2":
                return "twenty-$temp";
            case "3":
                return "thirty-$temp";
            case "4":
                return "forty-$temp";
            case "5":
                return "fifty-$temp";
            case "6":
                return "sixty-$temp";
            case "7":
                return "seventy-$temp";
            case "8":
                return "eighty-$temp";
            case "9":
                return "ninety-$temp";
        }
    }
}

function convertDigit($digit)
{
    switch ($digit)
    {
        case "0":
            return "zero";
        case "1":
            return "one";
        case "2":
            return "two";
        case "3":
            return "three";
        case "4":
            return "four";
        case "5":
            return "five";
        case "6":
            return "six";
        case "7":
            return "seven";
        case "8":
            return "eight";
        case "9":
            return "nine";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can build a function that reads backward the number and write down the text, adding "hundreed" or "tousend" depending of what the function discovers before the current digit.

Answer (score 38):

Alternatively, you can use the NumberFormatter class from [`intl`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.setup.php) package in PHP . Here's a sample code to get you started (for commandline):

```
<?php
if ($argc < 3) 
    {
    echo "usage: php {$argv[0]} lang-tag number ...\n";
    exit;
    }

array_shift($argv);
$lang_tag = array_shift($argv);

$nf1 = new NumberFormatter($lang_tag, NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$nf2 = new NumberFormatter($lang_tag, NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);

foreach ($argv as $num) 
    {
    echo $nf1->format($num).' is '.$nf2->format($num)."\n"; 
    }
```

Comment: Or more fitted to the original question:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php

`$nf = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT); for ($i=0;$i<100;$i++) echo $nf->format($i)."\n";`

Answer (score 9):

There is the [`Numbers_Words` package](http://pear.php.net/package/Numbers_Words) in PECL. It does exactly what you ask for. The following languages are supported:

- bg (Bulgarian) by Kouber Saparev
- cs (Czech) by Petr 'PePa' Pavel
- de (German) by Piotr Klaban
- dk (Danish) by Jesper Veggerby
- en_100 (Donald Knuth system, English) by Piotr Klaban
- en_GB (British English) by Piotr Klaban
- en_US (American English) by Piotr Klaban
- es (Spanish Castellano) by Xavier Noguer
- es_AR (Argentinian Spanish) by Martin Marrese
- et (Estonian) by Erkki Saarniit
- fr (French) by Kouber Saparev
- fr_BE (French Belgium) by Kouber Saparev and Philippe Bajoit
- he (Hebrew) by Hadar Porat
- hu_HU (Hungarian) by Nils Homp
- id (Indonesian) by Ernas M. Jamil and Arif Rifai Dwiyanto
- it_IT (Italian) by Filippo Beltramini and Davide Caironi
- lt (Lithuanian) by Laurynas Butkus
- nl (Dutch) by WHAM van Dinter
- pl (Polish) by Piotr Klaban
- pt_BR (Brazilian Portuguese) by Marcelo Subtil Marcal and Mario H.C.T.
- ru (Russian) by Andrey Demenev
- sv (Swedish) by Robin Ericsson

Comment: I am looking solution like BRUNEI DOLLARS THIRTY-FIVE THOUSAND SIX HUNDERED AND FORTY-TWO for 35,642.00. any suggestion, please share. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Using NumberFormatter class it is simple to get convert to words.

```
<?php

$number = '12345';
$locale = 'en_US';
$fmt = numfmt_create($locale, NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
$in_words = numfmt_format($fmt, $number);

print_r($in_words);
// twelve thousand three hundred forty-five

?>
```

Comment: That's already been shown in [an earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1107274/450127).

Answer (score 7):

I needed a solution that put 'and' into the returned string and formatted it into a sentence - typically as a human would say it. So I adapted a different solution slightly - posted as I thought this could be useful for someone.

```
4,835,301 returns "Four million eight hundred and thirty five thousand three hundred and one."
```

Code

```
function convertNumber($num = false)
{
    $num = str_replace(array(',', ''), '' , trim($num));
    if(! $num) {
        return false;
    }
    $num = (int) $num;
    $words = array();
    $list1 = array('', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven',
        'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'
    );
    $list2 = array('', 'ten', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety', 'hundred');
    $list3 = array('', 'thousand', 'million', 'billion', 'trillion', 'quadrillion', 'quintillion', 'sextillion', 'septillion',
        'octillion', 'nonillion', 'decillion', 'undecillion', 'duodecillion', 'tredecillion', 'quattuordecillion',
        'quindecillion', 'sexdecillion', 'septendecillion', 'octodecillion', 'novemdecillion', 'vigintillion'
    );
    $num_length = strlen($num);
    $levels = (int) (($num_length + 2) / 3);
    $max_length = $levels * 3;
    $num = substr('00' . $num, -$max_length);
    $num_levels = str_split($num, 3);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($num_levels); $i++) {
        $levels--;
        $hundreds = (int) ($num_levels[$i] / 100);
        $hundreds = ($hundreds ? ' ' . $list1[$hundreds] . ' hundred' . ( $hundreds == 1 ? '' : '' ) . ' ' : '');
        $tens = (int) ($num_levels[$i] % 100);
        $singles = '';
        if ( $tens < 20 ) {
            $tens = ($tens ? ' and ' . $list1[$tens] . ' ' : '' );
        } elseif ($tens >= 20) {
            $tens = (int)($tens / 10);
            $tens = ' and ' . $list2[$tens] . ' ';
            $singles = (int) ($num_levels[$i] % 10);
            $singles = ' ' . $list1[$singles] . ' ';
        }
        $words[] = $hundreds . $tens . $singles . ( ( $levels && ( int ) ( $num_levels[$i] ) ) ? ' ' . $list3[$levels] . ' ' : '' );
    } //end for loop
    $commas = count($words);
    if ($commas > 1) {
        $commas = $commas - 1;
    }
    $words = implode(' ',  $words);
    $words = preg_replace('/^\s\b(and)/', '', $words );
    $words = trim($words);
    $words = ucfirst($words);
    $words = $words . ".";
    return $words;
}
```

Comment: This solves the issue with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/3370633/9109998 when using eg 120000

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [NumberFormatter Class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php):

```
$f = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
echo $f->format($myNumber);
```

Comment: A short explanation of your code would make this answer stronger. This is particularly true for very old questions like this.

Comment: Duplicate of earlier answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1107274/450127

Answer (score 3):

I rewrote the code above to fit the standard U.S. written word number format.

```
function singledigit($number){
    switch($number){
        case 0:$word = "zero";break;
        case 1:$word = "one";break;
        case 2:$word = "two";break;
        case 3:$word = "three";break;
        case 4:$word = "four";break;
        case 5:$word = "five";break;
        case 6:$word = "six";break;
        case 7:$word = "seven";break;
        case 8:$word = "eight";break;
        case 9:$word = "nine";break;
    }
    return $word;
}

function doubledigitnumber($number){
    if($number == 0){
        $word = "";
    }
    else{
        $word = "-".singledigit($number);
    }       
    return $word;
}

function doubledigit($number){
    switch($number[0]){
        case 0:$word = doubledigitnumber($number[1]);break;
        case 1:
            switch($number[1]){
                case 0:$word = "ten";break;
                case 1:$word = "eleven";break;
                case 2:$word = "twelve";break;
                case 3:$word = "thirteen";break;
                case 4:$word = "fourteen";break;
                case 5:$word = "fifteen";break;
                case 6:$word = "sixteen";break;
                case 7:$word = "seventeen";break;
                case 8:$word = "eighteen";break;
                case 9:$word = "ninteen";break;
            }break;
        case 2:$word = "twenty".doubledigitnumber($number[1]);break;                
        case 3:$word = "thirty".doubledigitnumber($number[1]);break;
        case 4:$word = "forty".doubledigitnumber($number[1]);break;
        case 5:$word = "fifty".doubledigitnumber($number[1]);break;
        case 6:$word = "sixty".doubledigitnumber($number[1]);break;
        case 7:$word = "seventy".doubledigitnumber($number[1]);break;
        case 8:$word = "eighty".doubledigitnumber($number[1]);break;
        case 9:$word = "ninety".doubledigitnumber($number[1]);break;

    }
    return $word;
}

function unitdigit($numberlen,$number){
    switch($numberlen){         
        case 3:case 6:case 9:case 12:$word = "hundred";break;
        case 4:case 5:$word = "thousand";break;
        case 7:case 8:$word = "million";break;
        case 10:case 11:$word = "billion";break;
    }
    return $word;
}

function numberToWord($number){

    $numberlength = strlen($number);
    if ($numberlength == 1) { 
        return singledigit($number);
    }elseif ($numberlength == 2) {
        return doubledigit($number);
    }
    else {

        $word = "";
        $wordin = "";
        switch ($numberlength ) {
        case 5:case 8:  case 11:
            if($number[0] >0){
                $unitdigit = unitdigit($numberlength,$number[0]);
                $word = doubledigit($number[0].$number[1]) ." ".$unitdigit." ";
                return $word." ".numberToWord(substr($number,2));
            }
            else{
                return $word." ".numberToWord(substr($number,1));
            }
        break;
        default:
            if($number[0] >0){
                $unitdigit = unitdigit($numberlength,$number[0]);
                $word = singledigit($number[0]) ." ".$unitdigit." ";
            }               
            return $word." ".numberToWord(substr($number,1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: beautiful. however one small bug. try 100 002 and 103 002. for the first it will say one hundred two, where as the last one is correct. add this to unitdigiti method: 
        **if ($numberlen == 6 and $number[2] != 0) {
            $numberlen = 3;
        }**

and add this to the switch: **case 6:$word="hundred thousand";break;**

note that the unitdigit method now requires the full number to be passed $number instead of $number[0]

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. without using a library you just need to follow this..

First you need to check in your server if `;extension=php_intl.dll` is enabled in your **php.ini** if still not work you need to see this answer.

[intl extension php_intl.dll with wamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372888/intl-extension-php-intl-dll-with-wamp/16372984#16372984)

after successfully moving all the files starts with **icu**.

from: `<wamp_installation_path>/bin/php/php5.4.3/`

to: `<wamp_installation_path>/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/bin/`

and restart your server.

try to run this code:

```
$f = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
echo $f->format(123456);
```

it will show the output of ***one hundred twenty-three thousand four hundred fifty-six***.

hope that helps everyone :).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small class I wrote tonight. Caveats:

1. Only in English.
2. Only handles American/French definitions of billions, etc.
3. The `longform` method doesn't handle decimals. It just erases them. Feel free to modify this and add that functionality if you wish.
4. The `numberformat` method does do decimals, but doesn't do any rounding. I had to create a new `numberformat` function because of PHP's inherent limitations with integer sizes. I was translating numbers so big that when I used `number_format()` to check my translations, it took me 30 minutes to realize my translations weren't wrong, `number_format` was.
5. This isn't a caveat about the class, but about PHP. 32-bit versions of PHP will not handle integers bigger than `2,147,483,647` (2 billion and change). 64-bit versions will handle up to like `9 quintillion` or something. BUT that's irrelevant here as long as you feed the numbers to the `longform` method as a `string`. I did a 306-digit number over `ajax` from a webform just fine, as long as I passed it to the server as `''+number`.

So, this class will translate numbers up to `999 Centillion, 999 etc.` (e.g., a string of 9s 306 characters long). Any number bigger than that and the function just returns a dumb message.

Usage:

```
$number = '999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999';
reallyBig::longform($number);
```

The optional second boolean parameter defaults to true, which adds commas as best it can in the right places, to make the number more readable.

By the way, you can put a `-` at the front if you want it to be negative, but any other characters included in the inputted string will be stripped out. For instance:

`reallyBig::longform('-C55LL-M5-4-a-9u7-71m3-M8');` will output: `negative five billion, five hundred fifty-four million, nine hundred seventy-seven thousand, one hundred thirty-eight`

The `numberformat` method isn't necessary for any other method. It's just there if you want to check a really long translated number. Since all these functions handle numbers as strings, they don't run up against PHP's limitations.

The only reason I stopped at a 999 centillion is because centillion was the last number on the website I was looking at when I couldn't remember what came after a decillion.

```
class reallyBig
{
    private static $map, $strings;
    private static function map()
    {
        $map = array();
        $num = 1;
        $count = 1;
        while($num < 307)
        {
            if($count == 1) $map[$num] = $num+2;
            elseif($count == 2) $map[$num] = $num+1;
            else 
            {
                $map[$num] = $num;
                $count = 0;
            }
            $count++;
            $num++;
        }
        return $map;
    }
    private static function strings()
    {
        return array 
        (
            6 => 'thousand',
            9 => 'million',
            12 => 'billion',
            15 => 'trillion',
            18 => 'quadrillion',
            21 => 'quintillion',
            24 => 'sextillion',
            27 => 'septillion',
            30 => 'octillion',
            33 => 'nonillion',
            36 => 'decillion',
            39 => 'undecillion',
            42 => 'duodecillion',
            45 => 'tredecillion',
            48 => 'quattuordecillion',
            51 => 'quindecillion',
            54 => 'sexdecillion',
            57 => 'septendecillion',
            60 => 'octodecillion',
            63 => 'novemdecillion',
            66 => 'vigintillion',
            69 => 'unvigintillion',
            72 => 'duovigintillion',
            75 => 'trevigintillion',
            78 => 'quattuorvigintillion',
            81 => 'quinvigintillion',
            84 => 'sexvigintillion',
            87 => 'septenvigintillion',
            90 => 'octovigintillion',
            93 => 'novemvigintillion',
            96 => 'trigintillion',
            99 => 'untrigintillion',
            102 => 'duotrigintillion',
            105 => 'tretrigintillion',
            108 => 'quattuortrigintillion',
            111 => 'quintrigintillion',
            114 => 'sextrigintillion',
            117 => 'septentrigintillion',
            120 => 'octotrigintillion',
            123 => 'novemtrigintillion',
            126 => 'quadragintillion',
            129 => 'unquadragintillion',
            132 => 'duoquadragintillion',
            135 => 'trequadragintillion',
            138 => 'quattuorquadragintillion',
            141 => 'quinquadragintillion',
            144 => 'sexquadragintillion',
            147 => 'septenquadragintillion',
            150 => 'octoquadragintillion',
            153 => 'novemquadragintillion',
            156 => 'quinquagintillion',
            159 => 'unquinquagintillion',
            162 => 'duoquinquagintillion',
            165 => 'trequinquagintillion',
            168 => 'quattuorquinquagintillion',
            171 => 'quinquinquagintillion',
            174 => 'sexquinquagintillion',
            177 => 'septenquinquagintillion',
            180 => 'octoquinquagintillion',
            183 => 'novemquinquagintillion',
            186 => 'sexagintillion',
            189 => 'unsexagintillion',
            192 => 'duosexagintillion',
            195 => 'tresexagintillion',
            198 => 'quattuorsexagintillion',
            201 => 'quinsexagintillion',
            204 => 'sexsexagintillion',
            207 => 'septensexagintillion',
            210 => 'octosexagintillion',
            213 => 'novemsexagintillion',
            216 => 'septuagintillion',
            219 => 'unseptuagintillion',
            222 => 'duoseptuagintillion',
            225 => 'treseptuagintillion',
            228 => 'quattuorseptuagintillion',
            231 => 'quinseptuagintillion',
            234 => 'sexseptuagintillion',
            237 => 'septenseptuagintillion',
            240 => 'octoseptuagintillion',
            243 => 'novemseptuagintillion',
            246 => 'octogintillion',
            249 => 'unoctogintillion',
            252 => 'duooctogintillion',
            255 => 'treoctogintillion',
            258 => 'quattuoroctogintillion',
            261 => 'quinoctogintillion',
            264 => 'sexoctogintillion',
            267 => 'septenoctogintillion',
            270 => 'octooctogintillion',
            273 => 'novemoctogintillion',
            276 => 'nonagintillion',
            279 => 'unnonagintillion',
            282 => 'duononagintillion',
            285 => 'trenonagintillion',
            288 => 'quattuornonagintillion',
            291 => 'quinnonagintillion',
            294 => 'sexnonagintillion',
            297 => 'septennonagintillion',
            300 => 'octononagintillion',
            303 => 'novemnonagintillion',
            306 => 'centillion',
        );
    }
    public static function longform($number = string, $commas = true)
    {
        $negative = substr($number, 0, 1) == '-' ? 'negative ' : '';
        list($number) = explode('.', $number);          
        $number = trim(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/u", "", $number));
        $number = (string)(ltrim($number,'0'));
        if(empty($number)) return 'zero';
        $length = strlen($number);
        if($length <  2) return $negative.self::ones($number);
        if($length <  3) return $negative.self::tens($number);
        if($length <  4) return $commas ? $negative.str_replace('hundred ', 'hundred and ', self::hundreds($number)) : $negative.self::hundreds($number);
        if($length < 307) 
        {
            self::$map = self::map();
            self::$strings = self::strings();
            $result = self::beyond($number, self::$map[$length]);
            if(!$commas) return $negative.$result;
            $strings = self::$strings;
            $thousand = array_shift($strings);
            foreach($strings as $string) $result = str_replace($string.' ', $string.', ', $result);
            if(strpos($result, 'thousand') !== false) list($junk,$remainder) = explode('thousand', $result);
            else $remainder = $result;
            return strpos($remainder, 'hundred') !== false ? $negative.str_replace('thousand ', 'thousand, ', $result) : $negative.str_replace('thousand ', 'thousand and ', $result);
        }
        return 'a '.$negative.'number too big for your britches';
    }
    private static function ones($number)
    {
        $ones = array('zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine');
        return $ones[$number];
    }
    private static function tens($number)
    {
        $number = (string)(ltrim($number,'0'));
        if(strlen($number) < 2) return self::ones($number);
        if($number < 20)
        {
            $teens = array('ten','eleven','twelve','thirteen','fourteen','fifteen','sixteen','seventeen','eighteen','nineteen');
            return $teens[($number-10)];
        }
        else
        {
            $tens = array('','','twenty','thirty','forty','fifty','sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety');
            $word = $tens[$number[0]];
            return empty($number[1]) ? $word : $word.'-'.self::ones($number[1]);
        }
    }
    private static function hundreds($number)
    {
        $number = (string)(ltrim($number,'0'));
        if(strlen($number) < 3) return self::tens($number);
        $word = self::ones($number[0]).' hundred';
        $remainder = substr($number, -2);
        if(ltrim($remainder,'0') != '') $word .= ' '.self::tens($remainder);
        return $word;
    }
    private static function beyond($number, $limit)
    {
        $number = (string)(ltrim($number,'0'));
        $length = strlen($number);
        if($length < 4) return self::hundreds($number);
        if($length < ($limit-2)) return self::beyond($number, self::$map[($limit-3)]);
        if($length == $limit) $word = self::hundreds(substr($number, 0, 3), true);
        elseif($length == ($limit-1)) $word = self::tens(substr($number, 0, 2));
        else $word = self::ones($number[0]);
        $word .= ' '.self::$strings[$limit];
        $sub = ($limit-3);
        $remainder = substr($number, -$sub);
        if(ltrim($remainder,'0') != '') $word .= ' '.self::beyond($remainder, self::$map[$sub]);
        return $word;
    }
    public static function numberformat($number, $fixed = 0, $dec = '.', $thou = ',')
    {
        $negative = substr($number, 0, 1) == '-' ? '-' : '';
        $number = trim(preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/u", "", $number));
        $number = (string)(ltrim($number,'0'));
        $fixed = (int)$fixed;
        if(!is_numeric($fixed)) $fixed = 0;
        if(strpos($number, $dec) !== false) list($number,$decimals) = explode($dec, $number); 
        else $decimals = '0';
        if($fixed) $decimals = '.'.str_pad(substr($decimals, 0, $fixed), $fixed, 0, STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        else $decimals = '';
        $thousands = array_map('strrev', array_reverse(str_split(strrev($number), 3)));
        return $negative.implode($thou,$thousands).$decimals;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$grandTotalAmount = 700000000;
echo ($grandTotalAmount == round($grandTotalAmount)) ? convert_number_to_words(floatval($grandTotalAmount)) . ' Only' : convert_number_to_words(floatval($grandTotalAmount)) . ' Only';

function convert_number_to_words($number) {
    $hyphen = ' ';
    $conjunction = ' and ';
    $separator = ', ';
    $negative = 'negative ';
    $decimal = ' Thai Baht And ';
    $dictionary = array(
        0 => 'zero',
        1 => 'one',
        2 => 'two',
        3 => 'three',
        4 => 'four',
        5 => 'five',
        6 => 'six',
        7 => 'seven',
        8 => 'eight',
        9 => 'nine',
        10 => 'ten',
        11 => 'eleven',
        12 => 'twelve',
        13 => 'thirteen',
        14 => 'fourteen',
        15 => 'fifteen',
        16 => 'sixteen',
        17 => 'seventeen',
        18 => 'eighteen',
        19 => 'nineteen',
        20 => 'twenty',
        30 => 'thirty',
        40 => 'fourty',
        50 => 'fifty',
        60 => 'sixty',
        70 => 'seventy',
        80 => 'eighty',
        90 => 'ninety',
        100 => 'hundred',
        1000 => 'thousand',
        1000000 => 'million',
        1000000000 => 'billion',
        1000000000000 => 'trillion',
        1000000000000000 => 'quadrillion',
        1000000000000000000 => 'quintillion'
    );

    if (!is_numeric($number)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (($number >= 0 && (int) $number < 0) || (int) $number < 0 - PHP_INT_MAX) {
        // overflow
        trigger_error(
                'convert_number_to_words only accepts numbers between -' . PHP_INT_MAX . ' and ' . PHP_INT_MAX, E_USER_WARNING
        );
        return false;
    }

    if ($number < 0) {
        return $negative . convert_number_to_words(abs($number));
    }

    $string = $fraction = null;


    if (strpos($number, '.') !== false) {
        list($number, $fraction) = explode('.', $number);
    }

    switch (true) {
        case $number < 21:
            $string = $dictionary[$number];
            break;
        case $number < 100:
            $tens = ((int) ($number / 10)) * 10;
            $units = $number % 10;
            $string = $dictionary[$tens];
            if ($units) {
                $string .= $hyphen . $dictionary[$units];
            }
            break;
        case $number < 1000:
            $hundreds = $number / 100;
            $remainder = $number % 100;
            $string = $dictionary[$hundreds] . ' ' . $dictionary[100];
            if ($remainder) {
                $string .= $conjunction . convert_number_to_words($remainder);
            }
            break;
        default:
            $baseUnit = pow(1000, floor(log($number, 1000)));
            $numBaseUnits = (int) ($number / $baseUnit);
            $remainder = $number % $baseUnit;
            $string = convert_number_to_words($numBaseUnits) . ' ' . $dictionary[$baseUnit];
            if ($remainder) {
                $string .= $remainder < 100 ? $conjunction : $separator;
                $string .= convert_number_to_words($remainder);
            }
            break;
    }

    if (null !== $fraction && is_numeric($fraction)) {
        $string .= $decimal;
        $words = array();
        foreach (str_split((string) $fraction) as $number) {
            $words[] = $dictionary[$number];
        }
        $string .= implode(' ', $words);
    }

    return $string;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code is working fine

```
$test = 1000025.05;

$f = new \NumberFormatter( locale_get_default(), \NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT );

$word = $f->format($test);

echo $word;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected function numberTextHelper($number)
{
    if (($number < 0) || ($number > 999999999)) 
    {
        throw new Exception("Number is out of range");
    }
    
    $ones = array("", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eightteen", "Nineteen");
    $tens = array("", "", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Fourty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eigthy", "Ninety");
    
    $giga = floor($number / 1000000);
    // Millions (giga)
    $number -= $giga * 1000000;

    $thousands = floor($number / 1000);
    
    // Thousands (kilo)
    $number -= $thousands * 1000;
    
    $hecto = floor($number / 100);
    
    // Hundreds (hecto)
    $number -= $hecto * 100;
    
    $deca = floor($number / 10);
    
    // Tens (deca)
    $n = $number % 10;
    
    $frac  = round($number - (int)$number,2); 

    // Ones
    $result = array();
    if ($giga) 
    {
        $result[]= $this->numberTextHelper($giga).' '.($giga>1?'MILLIONS':'MILLION');
    }
    
    if ($thousands) 
    {
        $result[]= $thousands>1?$this->numberTextHelper($thousands).' THOUSANDS':'THOUSAND';
    }
    
    if ($hecto) 
    {
        $result[]= $this->numberTextHelper($hecto).'HUNDRED';
    }
    
    if ($deca) 
    {
        if($deca<2)
        {
            $result[]= $ones[$deca * 10 + $n];
            $n=0;
        }
        else
        {
            $result[]= $tens[$deca];
        }
    }
            

    if ($n) 
    {
        $result[]= $ones[$n];
    }

    if($frac) 
    {
        $result[]= 'and';
        $result[]= $this->numberTextHelper($frac*100);
        $result[]= 'cents';
    }
    
    if(empty($result)) 
    {
        $result[]= 'zero';
    }
    
    return implode(' ',$result);
}
```

And you can translate it

```
function numberText($number)
{
    $result=$this->numberTextHelper($number);
    $result=$this->strtoupper($result);
    $text=array_filter(explode(' ',$result));
    $translated=array_map(array($this,'getLang'),$text);
    return implode(' ',$translated);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I have generated this using a recursive function:

```
$wordnum = numberToWord($number);
echo $wordnum."<BR>";

function singledigit($number){
        switch($number){
            case 0:$word = "zero";break;
            case 1:$word = "One";break;
            case 2:$word = "two";break;
            case 3:$word = "three";break;
            case 4:$word = "Four";break;
            case 5:$word = "Five";break;
            case 6:$word = "Six";break;
            case 7:$word = "Seven";break;
            case 8:$word = "Eight";break;
            case 9:$word = "Nine";break;
        }
        return $word;
    }
    
    function doubledigitnumber($number){
        if($number == 0){
            $word = "";
        }
        else{
            $word = singledigit($number);
        }       
        return $word;
    }
    
    function doubledigit($number){
        switch($number[0]){
            case 0:$word = doubledigitnumber($number[1]);break;
            case 1:
                switch($number[1]){
                    case 0:$word = "Ten";break;
                    case 1:$word = "Eleven";break;
                    case 2:$word = "Twelve";break;
                    case 3:$word = "Thirteen";break;
                    case 4:$word = "Fourteen";break;
                    case 5:$word = "Fifteen";break;
                    case 6:$word = "Sixteen";break;
                    case 7:$word = "Seventeen";break;
                    case 8:$word = "Eighteen";break;
                    case 9:$word = "Ninteen";break;
                }break;
            case 2:$word = "Twenty".doubledigitnumber($number[1]);break;                
            case 3:$word = "Thirty".doubledigitnumber($number[1]);break;
            case 4:$word = "Forty".doubledigitnumber($number[1]);break;
            case 5:$word = "Fifty".doubledigitnumber($number[1]);break;
            case 6:$word = "Sixty".doubledigitnumber($number[1]);break;
            case 7:$word = "Seventy".doubledigitnumber($number[1]);break;
            case 8:$word = "Eighty".doubledigitnumber($number[1]);break;
            case 9:$word = "Ninety".doubledigitnumber($number[1]);break;
                
        }
        return $word;
    }
    
    function unitdigit($numberlen,$number){
        switch($numberlen){         
            case 3:$word = "Hundred";break;
            case 4:$word = "Thousand";break;
            case 5:$word = "Thousand";break;
            case 6:$word = "Lakh";break;
            case 7:$word = "Lakh";break;
            case 8:$word = "Crore";break;
            case 9:$word = "Crore";break;
            
        }
        return $word;
    }
    
    function numberToWord($number){
        
        $numberlength = strlen($number);
        if ($numberlength == 1) { 
            return singledigit($number);
        }elseif ($numberlength == 2) {
            return doubledigit($number);
        }
        else {
            
            $word = "";
            $wordin = "";
            
            if($numberlength == 9){
                if($number[0] >0){
                    $unitdigit = unitdigit($numberlength,$number[0]);
                    $word = doubledigit($number[0].$number[1]) ." ".$unitdigit." ";
                    return $word." ".numberToWord(substr($number,2));
                }
                else{
                    return $word." ".numberToWord(substr($number,1));
                }
            }
            
            if($numberlength == 7){
                if($number[0] >0){
                    $unitdigit = unitdigit($numberlength,$number[0]);
                    $word = doubledigit($number[0].$number[1]) ." ".$unitdigit." ";
                    return $word." ".numberToWord(substr($number,2));
                }
                else{
                    return $word." ".numberToWord(substr($number,1));
                }
                
            }
            
            if($numberlength == 5){
                if($number[0] >0){
                    $unitdigit = unitdigit($numberlength,$number[0]);
                    $word = doubledigit($number[0].$number[1]) ." ".$unitdigit." ";
                    return $word." ".numberToWord(substr($number,2));
                }
                else{
                    return $word." ".numberToWord(substr($number,1));
                }
                
                    
            }
            else{
                if($number[0] >0){
                    $unitdigit = unitdigit($numberlength,$number[0]);
                    $word = singledigit($number[0]) ." ".$unitdigit." ";
                }               
                return $word." ".numberToWord(substr($number,1));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code with $number = 123456789. The result was Twelve Crore  ThirtyFour Lakh  FiftySix Thousand  Seven Hundred  EightyNine. It should be One Hundred Twenty-Three Million, Four Hundred Fifty-Six Thousand, Seven Hundred Eighty-Nine.

Comment: From wikipedia: "A crore is a unit in the South Asian numbering system equal to ten million" - I believe that the OP wanted the converted number in English

Comment: Too many switch cases. Consider using simple arrays which is also faster.

Answer (score -3):

```
Amount in Words:</b><?=no_to_words($number)?>
```

A very simple way to convert numbers to words using the PHP function.

Comment: That's the custom function, you should provide the source to that function