# php print integer in words

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting a number (1, 2, 3) to a string (one, two, three) in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112571/converting-a-number-1-2-3-to-a-string-one-two-three-in-php)

I have a form in which products will be listed out when,i clich total chk box it will be calculated but,it will be integera only,i want this to print in words.

For eg:217 it should print in words two hundred seven only. Hope,this is clear.

Thnx in advance

Comment: *(Duplicate):* [Converting a number (1, 2, 3) to a string (one, two, three) in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112571/converting-a-number-1-2-3-to-a-string-one-two-three-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

[PEAR's Numbers Words](http://pear.php.net/package/Numbers_Words/) is old, but competent.

Comment: How do,i do it?Can,you guide me.Pls

Comment: Is there any function which does this conversion job?

Answer (score 0):

The [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112571/converting-a-number-1-2-3-to-a-string-one-two-three-in-php) seems to answer this quite well, DAFFODIL, have a look there. You will have to have PEAR installed. Easiest way is to try `Numbers_Words::toWords(200)` and see if that throws up an error.

Comment: While,i tried to install pear i got this HTTP proxy (host:port)   : 

what should i fill?