# Convert number to letter with php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting a number (1, 2, 3) to a string (one, two, three) in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112571/converting-a-number-1-2-3-to-a-string-one-two-three-in-php)

I'm programming an invoice script. I'm looking for a php script that convert number to letter.
Exemple, the invoice show this value : 155€

The script put automatically: ONE HUNDRED FIFTY FIVE

Any ideas ?

Thank you :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to convert a number to a word in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277569/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-word-in-php) and [Converting a number (1, 2, 3) to a string (one, two, three) in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112571/converting-a-number-1-2-3-to-a-string-one-two-three-in-php)

Answer (score 5):

Can use

- http://pear.php.net/package/Numbers_Words

> With Numbers_Words class you can convert numbers
>   written in arabic digits to words in several languages.
>   You can convert an integer between -infinity and infinity.
>   If your system does not support such long numbers you can
>   call Numbers_Words::toWords() with just a string.
>
> With the Numbers_Words::toCurrency($num, $locale, 'USD') method
>   you can convert a number (decimal and fraction part) to words with currency name.

Answer (score 5):

Try looking into [NumberFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) for PHP.

Sample Script:

```
<?php

$f = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
echo $f->format(123456);

?>
```

Produces the result:
`one hundred twenty-three thousand four hundred fifty-six`

Answer (score 2):

Or, if you don't have PEAR or don't want to use PEAR you can try:

http://krishnasrikanth.in/2010/04/10/number-to-words-in-php

Greetings, and good luck ;)

Usage:

```
$converter=new NumbWordter();
echo $converter->convert(1823912);
// echoes - One million, eight hundred and twenty three thousand, nine hundred and twelve
```

Comment: Could you please let me know the usage code? Thank You

Comment: This is a nice start and works with your demo number but if you try say 120000 it will return "One hundred and twenty zero thousand, zero hundred and"

Comment: Found this solution which solves the problem with 120000 stackoverflow.com/a/45125817/9109998