# convert large number to spoken english

Tags: php, math, bc

Converting 'small' numbers to English is not to troublesome. But if you handle BCMath Arbitrary Precision numbers then it can be.

Using code from:

http://marc.info/?l=php-general&m=99928281523866&w=2

The maximum number seems to be:

> two billion one hundred forty seven
>   million four hundred eighty three
>   thousand six hundred forty seven

Anyone know a function to convert numbers bigger than that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert number to letter with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370609/convert-number-to-letter-with-php)

Comment: I think that such limit is not given by the algorithm, but by the size of the underlying integer type (the number you wrote is the maximum number representable with a 32 bit signed integer); I suppose that just changing that code to make it work with your bignum library should give you a much wider range. Besides, as @sexyprout already said, spelling such big numbers is pointless.

Comment: @Gordon Not a dupe, this question is about converting numbers larger than PHP_MAX_INT.

Comment: @Artefacto: "With Numbers_Words class you can convert numbers written in arabic digits to words in several languages. You can convert an integer **between -infinity and infinity**. If your system does not support such long numbers you can call Numbers_Words::toWords() with just a string."

Comment: @Gordon Fair enough, but the fact the answer is the same doesn't mean the question is also the same :p

Comment: @Artefacto but the solution is the same, so I think it's fair to close it as a duplicate unless the OP points out why that solution doesnt solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your own function, I suggest to use numbers as a string, let a substract like this:

```
    $string =  "12356";
    $text="";
    // level means 0-ones, 1- thousand , 2 million, 3 billion etc...
    $level=0;
    //until string has no character left
    while ($len=getval($string)){
      // get partial number from 0 to 999
      $string_partial = substr($string, (strlen($string)-$len)) ;
      // get hundreds
      $hund = ($string_partial - ($string_partial % 100))/100;
      // get tens
      $tens = $string_partial - ($hund *100);
      $tens = ($tens - ($tens %10))/10;
      // get ones
      $ones = $string_partial - ($tens*10) - ($hund*100);
      // remove partial_string form original string             
      $string = substr($string, 0, (strlen($string)-$len));
      // edbug echoing
      echo $level . " - " . $hund. " - " . $tens .  " - " . $ones . "<br>";
      // you need to create a function that convert number to text only from 0 to 999 to set correct million/thousand etc, use $level.
      //$text = getTextvalue($hund,$tens,$ones,$level).$text;
      //increment $level
      $level++;
    }
    function getval($n){
      switch (strlen($n)){
       case 0: return false;
       case 1: return 1;
       case 2: return 2;
       default: return 3;
       }
    }
```

example:

```
$string =  "123456789";
```

will output

```
 $level - $hund - $tens - $ones
 0 - 7 - 8 - 9  
 1 - 4 - 5 - 6  //thousand
 2 - 1 - 2 - 3  //million
```

Answer (score 0):

For numbers larger than `PHP_MAX_INT`, you'll have to either write the function on rely on an external service, such as [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com).

The only functionality PHP offers for this is Intl's [`NumberFormatter`](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.create.php). `NumberFormatter::format` accepts floats, but this means it can only handle integers up to 2^63-1 in 64-bit long architectures or 52-bit numbers in 32-bit ones.

Comment: having to use Wolfram's super computer would be a bit overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the vpi2english function to handle integers as large as 10^306 - 1. It is part of my [VPI toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725-variable-precision-integer-arithmetic).

```
vpi2english(vpi('12000000110022987')) 
ans = 
twelve quadrillion, one hundred ten million, twenty two thousand, nine hundred eighty seven
```

Comment: At what point would you say it becomes meaningless. For example, how many people understand what a quadrillion means? I don't!

Comment: nice try but the question is tagged php.

Comment: @Yehonatan: The point is obvious. Since @woodchips has already gone through this exercise he will have a subjective sense of where the utility of this starts to diminish. It wasn't a comment, it was a question.