# How to spell out a number in english words

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert number to letter with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370609/convert-number-to-letter-with-php)

Hello,

I am working on receipt and i want to show cost in words too, for example it could write five thousand for entry of 5000. I am using smarty, php, mysql.

Comment: What is the question? Please add more details and explain clearly what do you want. It's not bad to take a look at this -> [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your question titles are very hazy. Try to make them clearer and more generic so people scrolling through the list can understand what the actual problem is - it will attract more people (fixed this one for you)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this script: [Re: [PHP] number to word](http://marc.info/?l=php-general&m=99928281523866&w=2)