# convert number to word in php not working

Tags: php, html

Please note, the following PHP code converts amount in number to amount in words. This works fine for integer like (ex. 5250) and when it with decimal it gives wrong results.

**Ex:** for  450 = four hundred fifty only.
**Ex:** for  450.5 = four thousand five hundred five (which is wrong) and it should be four hundred fifty and fifty paisa only.

I have checked in the web analysed but unable to rectify the code. Can any body suggest /correct the code please?

```
<?php
    function inr($number){
        //A function to convert numbers into words.
        $words = array(
        '0'=> '' ,'1'=> 'one' ,'2'=> 'two' ,'3' => 'three','4' => 'four','5' => 'five',
        '6' => 'six','7' => 'seven','8' => 'eight','9' => 'nine','10' => 'ten',
        '11' => 'eleven','12' => 'twelve','13' => 'thirteen','14' => 'fouteen','15' => 'fifteen',
        '16' => 'sixteen','17' => 'seventeen','18' => 'eighteen','19' => 'nineteen','20' => 'twenty',
        '30' => 'thirty','40' => 'fourty','50' => 'fifty','60' => 'sixty','70' => 'seventy',
        '80' => 'eighty','90' => 'ninty');

        //First find the length of the number
        $number_length = strlen($number);
        //Initialize an empty array
        $number_array = array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);        
        $received_number_array = array();

        //Store all received numbers into an array
        for($i=0;$i<$number_length;$i++){    $received_number_array[$i] = substr($number,$i,1);    }

        //Populate the empty array with the numbers received - most critical operation
        for($i=9-$number_length,$j=0;$i<9;$i++,$j++){ $number_array[$i] = $received_number_array[$j]; }
        $number_to_words_string = "";        
        //Finding out whether it is teen ? and then multiplying by 10, example 17 is seventeen, so if 1 is preceeded with 7 multiply 1 by 10 and add 7 to it.
        for($i=0,$j=1;$i<9;$i++,$j++){
            if($i==0 || $i==2 || $i==4 || $i==7){
                if($number_array[$i]=="1"){
                    $number_array[$j] = 10+$number_array[$j];
                    $number_array[$i] = 0;
                }        
            }
        }

        $value = "";
        for($i=0;$i<9;$i++){
            if($i==0 || $i==2 || $i==4 || $i==7){    $value = $number_array[$i]*10; }
            else{ $value = $number_array[$i];    }            
            if($value!=0){ $number_to_words_string.= $words["$value"]." "; }
            if($i==1 && $value!=0){    $number_to_words_string.= "Crores "; }
            if($i==3 && $value!=0){    $number_to_words_string.= "Lakhs ";    }
            if($i==5 && $value!=0){    $number_to_words_string.= "Thousand "; }
            if($i==6 && $value!=0){    $number_to_words_string.= "Hundred "; }
        }
        if($number_length>9){ $number_to_words_string = "Sorry This does not support more than 99 Crores"; }
        return ucwords(strtolower("Rupees ".$number_to_words_string)." Only.");

    }


?>
```

Comment: why are you not using an existing library? Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370609/convert-number-to-letter-with-php

Comment: I have checked, but they are not clear what I meant is?

Comment: If you ever get this up and running, I suggest you post some of your code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. There are a lot of things wrong with your code which I think you should get sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

you need to explode values after decimal point like

```
$numberarr = explode('.',$number);
        $number = $numberarr[0];
        $number_length = strlen($number);
//output Rupees Four Hundred Fifty Only.
```

also need more work on `$numberarr[1] //we get after (.) values`

Answer (score 0):

why you have written `$my_fig=inr(450.5)` what is `inr()` function ?
try using `intval()` replacing `inr()`..

Answer (score 0):

The problem starts here:

```
$number_length = strlen($number);
```

Consider the following numbers:

```
1234
12.3
```

The two numbers are clearly different orders of magnitude, but since your code centers around the string length, it treats the numbers as though they were the same order of magnitude. Because of this bad assumption, the answer returned is incorrect.

To fix the problem, recognize that a different system is used to create word values for the numbers before the decimals than after. For this reason, you need to first split the number at the decimal and process the two parts separately.

```
$integer_value = floor($number);

if (strstr($number, '.')) {
    $decimal_value = (int)substr($number, strpos($number, '.'));
    // Convert $decimal_value to its word value
}
```

There are well-tested libraries that will do all of this for you, so unless this is just a learning exercise I suggest that you make use of one of those.