# Number conversion to string (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new in Laravel and I'm trying to convert a number/amount to string in laravel.

Example:
Number/amount: 1,500
Converted: One Thousand, Five Hundred

How do I suppose to do that? please help thanks

Comment: Possible Duplicated! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370609/convert-number-to-letter-with-php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to convert a number to a word in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277569/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-word-in-php)

Comment: if the NumberFormatter is used than in laravel it gives an error as it treat as a model.

Answer (score 13):

Use PHP `NumberFormatter` class for conversion :

```
$digit = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
echo $digit->format(1000);
```

Output will be: 
`one thousand`

Answer (score 2):

```
public static function convert_number_to_words($number) {

        $hyphen      = '-';
        $conjunction = ' and ';
        $separator   = ', ';
        $negative    = 'negative ';
        $decimal     = ' point ';
        $dictionary  = array(
            0                   => 'zero',
            1                   => 'one',
            2                   => 'two',
            3                   => 'three',
            4                   => 'four',
            5                   => 'five',
            6                   => 'six',
            7                   => 'seven',
            8                   => 'eight',
            9                   => 'nine',
            10                  => 'ten',
            11                  => 'eleven',
            12                  => 'twelve',
            13                  => 'thirteen',
            14                  => 'fourteen',
            15                  => 'fifteen',
            16                  => 'sixteen',
            17                  => 'seventeen',
            18                  => 'eighteen',
            19                  => 'nineteen',
            20                  => 'twenty',
            30                  => 'thirty',
            40                  => 'fourty',
            50                  => 'fifty',
            60                  => 'sixty',
            70                  => 'seventy',
            80                  => 'eighty',
            90                  => 'ninety',
            100                 => 'hundred',
            1000                => 'thousand',
            1000000             => 'million',
            1000000000          => 'billion',
            1000000000000       => 'trillion',
            1000000000000000    => 'quadrillion',
            1000000000000000000 => 'quintillion'
        );

        if (!is_numeric($number)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (($number >= 0 && (int) $number < 0) || (int) $number < 0 - PHP_INT_MAX) {
            // overflow
            trigger_error(
                'convert_number_to_words only accepts numbers between -' . PHP_INT_MAX . ' and ' . PHP_INT_MAX,
                E_USER_WARNING
            );
            return false;
        }

        if ($number < 0) {
            return $negative . Self::convert_number_to_words(abs($number));
        }

        $string = $fraction = null;

        if (strpos($number, '.') !== false) {
            list($number, $fraction) = explode('.', $number);
        }

        switch (true) {
            case $number < 21:
                $string = $dictionary[$number];
                break;
            case $number < 100:
                $tens   = ((int) ($number / 10)) * 10;
                $units  = $number % 10;
                $string = $dictionary[$tens];
                if ($units) {
                    $string .= $hyphen . $dictionary[$units];
                }
                break;
            case $number < 1000:
                $hundreds  = $number / 100;
                $remainder = $number % 100;
                $string = $dictionary[$hundreds] . ' ' . $dictionary[100];
                if ($remainder) {
                    $string .= $conjunction . Self::convert_number_to_words($remainder);
                }
                break;
            default:
                $baseUnit = pow(1000, floor(log($number, 1000)));
                $numBaseUnits = (int) ($number / $baseUnit);
                $remainder = $number % $baseUnit;
                $string = Self::convert_number_to_words($numBaseUnits) . ' ' . $dictionary[$baseUnit];
                if ($remainder) {
                    $string .= $remainder < 100 ? $conjunction : $separator;
                    $string .= Self::convert_number_to_words($remainder);
                }
                break;
        }

        if (null !== $fraction && is_numeric($fraction)) {
            $string .= $decimal;
            $words = array();
            foreach (str_split((string) $fraction) as $number) {
                $words[] = $dictionary[$number];
            }
            $string .= implode(' ', $words);
        }

        return $string;
    }
```

You can access the function wherever you want within the program as

```
Classname::convert_number_to_words(123456789.123);
// one hundred and twenty-three million, four hundred and fifty-six thousand, seven hundred and eighty-nine point one two three
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
/**
 * English Number Converter - Collection of PHP functions to convert a number
 *                            into English text.
 *
 * This exact code is licensed under CC-Wiki on Stackoverflow.
 * http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
 *
 * @link     http://stackoverflow.com/q/277569/367456
 * @question Is there an easy way to convert a number to a word in PHP?
 *
 * This file incorporates work covered by the following copyright and
 * permission notice:
 *
 *   Copyright 2007-2008 Brenton Fletcher. http://bloople.net/num2text
 *   You can use this freely and modify it however you want.
 */

function convertNumber($number)
{
    list($integer, $fraction) = explode(".", (string) $number);

    $output = "";

    if ($integer{0} == "-")
    {
        $output = "negative ";
        $integer    = ltrim($integer, "-");
    }
    else if ($integer{0} == "+")
    {
        $output = "positive ";
        $integer    = ltrim($integer, "+");
    }

    if ($integer{0} == "0")
    {
        $output .= "zero";
    }
    else
    {
        $integer = str_pad($integer, 36, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $group   = rtrim(chunk_split($integer, 3, " "), " ");
        $groups  = explode(" ", $group);

        $groups2 = array();
        foreach ($groups as $g)
        {
            $groups2[] = convertThreeDigit($g{0}, $g{1}, $g{2});
        }

        for ($z = 0; $z < count($groups2); $z++)
        {
            if ($groups2[$z] != "")
            {
                $output .= $groups2[$z] . convertGroup(11 - $z) . (
                        $z < 11
                        && !array_search('', array_slice($groups2, $z + 1, -1))
                        && $groups2[11] != ''
                        && $groups[11]{0} == '0'
                            ? " and "
                            : ", "
                    );
            }
        }

        $output = rtrim($output, ", ");
    }

    if ($fraction > 0)
    {
        $output .= " point";
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($fraction); $i++)
        {
            $output .= " " . convertDigit($fraction{$i});
        }
    }

    return $output;
}

function convertGroup($index)
{
    switch ($index)
    {
        case 11:
            return " decillion";
        case 10:
            return " nonillion";
        case 9:
            return " octillion";
        case 8:
            return " septillion";
        case 7:
            return " sextillion";
        case 6:
            return " quintrillion";
        case 5:
            return " quadrillion";
        case 4:
            return " trillion";
        case 3:
            return " billion";
        case 2:
            return " million";
        case 1:
            return " thousand";
        case 0:
            return "";
    }
}

function convertThreeDigit($digit1, $digit2, $digit3)
{
    $buffer = "";

    if ($digit1 == "0" && $digit2 == "0" && $digit3 == "0")
    {
        return "";
    }

    if ($digit1 != "0")
    {
        $buffer .= convertDigit($digit1) . " hundred";
        if ($digit2 != "0" || $digit3 != "0")
        {
            $buffer .= " and ";
        }
    }

    if ($digit2 != "0")
    {
        $buffer .= convertTwoDigit($digit2, $digit3);
    }
    else if ($digit3 != "0")
    {
        $buffer .= convertDigit($digit3);
    }

    return $buffer;
}

function convertTwoDigit($digit1, $digit2)
{
    if ($digit2 == "0")
    {
        switch ($digit1)
        {
            case "1":
                return "ten";
            case "2":
                return "twenty";
            case "3":
                return "thirty";
            case "4":
                return "forty";
            case "5":
                return "fifty";
            case "6":
                return "sixty";
            case "7":
                return "seventy";
            case "8":
                return "eighty";
            case "9":
                return "ninety";
        }
    } else if ($digit1 == "1")
    {
        switch ($digit2)
        {
            case "1":
                return "eleven";
            case "2":
                return "twelve";
            case "3":
                return "thirteen";
            case "4":
                return "fourteen";
            case "5":
                return "fifteen";
            case "6":
                return "sixteen";
            case "7":
                return "seventeen";
            case "8":
                return "eighteen";
            case "9":
                return "nineteen";
        }
    } else
    {
        $temp = convertDigit($digit2);
        switch ($digit1)
        {
            case "2":
                return "twenty-$temp";
            case "3":
                return "thirty-$temp";
            case "4":
                return "forty-$temp";
            case "5":
                return "fifty-$temp";
            case "6":
                return "sixty-$temp";
            case "7":
                return "seventy-$temp";
            case "8":
                return "eighty-$temp";
            case "9":
                return "ninety-$temp";
        }
    }
}

function convertDigit($digit)
{
    switch ($digit)
    {
        case "0":
            return "zero";
        case "1":
            return "one";
        case "2":
            return "two";
        case "3":
            return "three";
        case "4":
            return "four";
        case "5":
            return "five";
        case "6":
            return "six";
        case "7":
            return "seven";
        case "8":
            return "eight";
        case "9":
            return "nine";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the PHP built-in `NumberFormatter` class and Ensure to enable this extension in php.ini by uncommenting this line: `extension=php_intl.dll`

Comment: In my case the line I had to uncomment in php.ini was ;extension=intl

Answer (score 0):

Read this , there is number class for php.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php