# PHP increase word (one -> two -> three)

Tags: php

I am trying in PHP to use a plugin.

I need to achieve this:

```
<div id="elementone">
  <p>TEST</p>
</div>

<div id="elementwo">
  <p>TEST</p>
</div>
```

However I need to use PHP to increment the value from **one** into **two** I know you can do numeric increments however, I don not know how to do this apart from looking into an array?

Comment: Why can't you use `element1` and `element2`? That's a *very* poorly designed plugin if it really does require you to use `one`, `two`, etc... There is no way to do what you're trying to do, you can't increment *words*. You'll have to store a big array, or write/find a custom function to turn arbitrary numbers into words.

Comment: uh? posting your array and defining better what you are trying to achieve will help you

Comment: What is wrong with using an array?
Have a read at this link which converts numbers to their word equivalent: http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/convert-numbers-to-words-with-php/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example in [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php) documentation.

```
 function int_to_words($x) {
global $nwords;

if(!is_numeric($x))
  $w = '#';
else if(fmod($x, 1) != 0)
  $w = '#';
else {
  if($x < 0) {
     $w = 'minus ';
     $x = -$x;
  } else
     $w = '';
  // ... now $x is a non-negative integer.

  if($x < 21)   // 0 to 20
     $w .= $nwords[$x];
  else if($x < 100) {   // 21 to 99
     $w .= $nwords[10 * floor($x/10)];
     $r = fmod($x, 10);
     if($r > 0)
        $w .= '-'. $nwords[$r];
  } else if($x < 1000) {   // 100 to 999
     $w .= $nwords[floor($x/100)] .' hundred';
     $r = fmod($x, 100);
     if($r > 0)
        $w .= ' and '. int_to_words($r);
  } else if($x < 1000000) {   // 1000 to 999999
     $w .= int_to_words(floor($x/1000)) .' thousand';
     $r = fmod($x, 1000);
     if($r > 0) {
        $w .= ' ';
        if($r < 100)
           $w .= 'and ';
        $w .= int_to_words($r);
     }
  } else {    //  millions
     $w .= int_to_words(floor($x/1000000)) .' million';
     $r = fmod($x, 1000000);
     if($r > 0) {
        $w .= ' ';
        if($r < 100)
           $word .= 'and ';
        $w .= int_to_words($r);
     }
  }
}
return $w;
}
```

Comment: and the follow up question is... is it worth the hassle?

Comment: As "Martin Perry" said it may be easier to use numbers. Good shout here!

Comment: I completely agree, and would advise against using the example that I have provided, but this function does do what the question asks. Maybe it will be helpful for someone in the future. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way how to convert 1 => "one", 2 => "two" without array look-up. YOu should name your elements as `element#number`

Or you could use this: [Converting a number (1, 2, 3) to a string (one, two, three) in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112571/converting-a-number-1-2-3-to-a-string-one-two-three-in-php)

Comment: Thanks! How you would go about coding this? I would imagine that I would need to hit a max of 30...

Comment: @Neil I would use for-loop... but your question is not soo understandable

Answer (score 1):

Google comes very handy at times. Read here if you want to stick to that rather poor design choice: http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/convert-numbers-to-words-with-php/

The bottom line: you **can't** do it unless you read the number strings from an array, an object, etc...