# Converting an array in php

Tags: php

I have an array like this

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( 
        [label] => G2 ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [label] => Samsung Galaxy S4 ) )
```

I want to convert it into an array something like this

```
array (
    'label' => array(
        'optionone' => array('G2'),
        'optiontwo' => array('Samsung Galaxy S4'))),
```

Comment: Do you strictly want `optionone` ,`optiontwo` as key or is it ok it to be numerical like `1`,`2` etc ?

Comment: nummerical values also fyn :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a number (1, 2, 3) to a string (one, two, three) in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112571/converting-a-number-1-2-3-to-a-string-one-two-three-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Since numerical values are also fine, try this

```
$newArray = array('label');
foreach ( $array = $k=>$a ) {
    $newArray['label'][ 'option' . $k+1 ] = $a['label'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to **foreach** the Array to iterate each index **[0] , [1]** etc. and inside array you have to make a multidimensional array

```
 $var['label'][] = $value; .
```

However for associative array like optionone , optiontwo you have to concat 'option' + convert integer 1 ,2 ,3 to one , two , three etc.

for **converting 1 ,2 ,3 to one , two , three**. check here please 
[Converting a number (1, 2, 3) to a string (one, two, three) in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112571/converting-a-number-1-2-3-to-a-string-one-two-three-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

I think this gives what you want, but the structure looks a bit odd to me. Also there might be a magic function that populates `$num2str`.

```
$a = Array (Array ( 'label' => 'G2' ), Array ( 'label' => 'Samsung Galaxy S4' ) );
$b = array();
$num2str = array('one', 'two', 'three', ..);
foreach($a as $i => $phone_info) {
  $b['label']['option' . $num2str[$i]] => array($phone_info['label']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`option1`, `option2` keys will be more useful instead of `optionone`, `optiontow`,

try this code

```
$array1 = Array (Array ("label" => "G2" ), Array ( "label" => "Samsung Galaxy S4" ) );
$array2 = array();
$array2['label'] = array();
for($i=0; $i < count($array1); $i++){
 $array2['label']["option{$i}"] = $array1[$i]['label'];
}
print_r($array2);
```