# How to change echo text based on some value??? php

Tags: php

I got input type field and value in that field is changing when I move bar on range slider.
Can someone help me to write some if condition.

I want when the value is 1 to echo "one"... when value is 2 to echo "two"...

here is range slider and input type="text" with values.

[link to page I am trying to do :)](http://gia-online.com/vps)

Thanks!

Comment: While @Ja͢ck's answer will work it isnt scalable as you have not provided any functionality for this. You are getting either a true or false boolean returned which decides what string to output.

Comment: Well this value from range slider is planed to be some kind of trigger and based on the value to echo some text msg. I got 5 range values.

Comment: based on that url, its  javascript you want *not* PHP

Comment: `<input type="range">` is not widely supported in browsers.

Comment: I thought that php can solve this, if I need javascript help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bored enough to bother:

```
$out=array('1'=>'one','2'=>'two'); //etc

echo $out[$_POST['selected']];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question, as phrased, is going to be difficult to answer. Here's why:

1. You are working with an interaction between an HTML web form and a PHP script. However, you didn't provide any example code, so it's impossible to know how you are setting up this interaction.
2. It might be better to approach this purely as a javascript or jQuery solution - but without knowing what you are doing with the end result, it's impossible to make that judgment or offer guidance.
3. If you are hoping for a strict PHP solution, how would you like the data returned - if you need it returned at all. A PHP script to do what you ask is fairly simple - but the return portion can be involved.
4. Perhaps you're simply looking for the PHP [switch statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)?
5. Are you actually trying to convert an int or float to it's string text? Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112571/converting-a-number-1-2-3-to-a-string-one-two-three-in-php)...

Finally, you might want to review the write-up on asking [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You'll get better answers.

mnr