# how to return select box stored values in html

Tags: php, html, mysql

i am trying to display the stored values from select box. now below select value is stored in MySQL field name 'age'. example: Three as value 3

```
<select name="age">
      <option value="1">one</option> 
      <option value="2">two</option>
      <option value="3">three</option>
      <option value="4">four</option>
      <option value="5">five</option>
      <option value="6">six</option>
      <option value="7">seven</option>
      <option value="8">eight</option>
      <option value="9">nine</option>
      <option value="ten">10</option>
      </select>
```

Result:

when i am trying to display `<?=age?>` in PHP its showing just 3 but i want to display in words `three`

Comment: you would need to use javascript to do that. PHP executes before the html is rendered and has no concept of a select menu or it's contents as such

Comment: if you don't know answer don't touch. i don't want you negative voting

Comment: ok i will try javascript

Comment: Your question is not clear. Where do You get <?=$get?> ?

Comment: Than use value = "three" instead of value ="3" . as u r already using ten for 10

Comment: If its only about converting numbers to words, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112571/converting-a-number-1-2-3-to-a-string-one-two-three-in-php

Comment: @sanderbee if its about converting than y using ten for 10?