# How Can I change a number to string

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an easy way to convert a number to a word in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277569/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-word-in-php)

Recently I needed to change a number to string just like below in php

```
$str=100;

{ Here will be the code which will return One Hundred not 100}
```

so **$str=150** then will return **one hundred fifty**

How can I do it. How can I change the number to text in php (**NB:** number will be random)
please help me

Comment: Have you tried anything or do you just want someone to code it for you?

Comment: Hhh, homework? Anyway: `$expontents = array( 1000000000 => 'billion', 1000000 = 'million', 1000 => 'thousand', 100 => 'hundred'); $decades = array( 10 => 'ten', 20 => 'twenty'), $numbers = array( 'zero', 'one', 'two'), $specials => array( 11 => 'eleven')` and `%<>+-*/, floor` is way to go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Numbers_Words](http://pear.php.net/package/Numbers_Words) Pear package.

Example.

```
 require('Numbers/Words.php');
 $number = 150;
 $nw = new Numbers_Words();
 $numw = $nw->toWords($number);

 echo $numw; //one hundred fifty
```

Comment: Has anyone tried numbers greater than 999,999,999 (a billion and above)? 1,000,000,000 says "One Thousand Million" !?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem has been suggested in the comments of the php documentation at the following location: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php#97020

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

There is a PEAR package that will do this for you ...

http://pear.php.net/package-info.php?package=Numbers_Words