# how to convert currency into a string in php

Tags: php, currency

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an easy way to convert a number to a word in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277569/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-word-in-php)

I want to ask, for example, there is a price to 110 000 the number format as the result of the conversion to a string to be "one hundred and ten thousand". how the coding for php?

eg.

```
  $price = 110000;
  $price_string = "one hundred and ten thousand"
```

please help me. thank you

Comment: A quick google search found this class: http://www.jaygilford.com/php/number-to-text-converting-php-class/, try it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this library](http://pear.php.net/package-info.php?package=Numbers_Words), for example. Or [this code snippet](http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/convert-numbers-to-words-with-php/) if you don't want to add external code into your project.