# str_replace issue (letters and numbers)

Tags: php, string, replace, str-replace

I have numbers that I would like to replace with letters:

```
<?php
$text = 'I have 10 apples';
$numbers = array(0, 1, 2,..., 10);
$letters = array('zero', 'one', 'two',... 'ten');
echo str_replace($numbers, $letters, $text); 
// output is 'I have onezero apples' instead of 'I have ten apples'
?>
```

How could it be done to generate correct output? It should also work not only for numbers but also for words (inside `$number` array may be also letters/words)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply sort array descending with key length and it will both for numbers and other strings. The following code should work for you:

```
<?php
$text = 'I have 10 (or 21) apples and I would like to bake an apple pie';
$numbers = array(0, 1, 2, 10, 21, ' a ', ' an ');
$letters = array('zero', 'one', 'two','ten','twenty one',' A ',' AN ');

$data = array_combine($numbers, $letters);

krsort($data, SORT_STRING);

echo str_replace(array_keys($data), array_values($data), $text);

// Output: I have ten (or twenty one) apples and I would like to bake AN apple pie
?>
```

**EDIT**

For the following input data:

```
$text = 'An 1 Anha 2 Anh 21';
$numbers = array(0, 1, 2, 10, 21, ' a ', ' an ', 'An','Anh', 'Anha');
$letters = array('zero', 'one', 'two','ten','twenty one',' A ',' AN ', 'Hi', 'Hello', 'Bye');

$data = array_combine($numbers, $letters);

krsort($data, SORT_STRING);

echo str_replace(array_keys($data), array_values($data), $text);
```

using the same method will give you:

> Hi one Bye two Hello twenty one

output as intended

**How does it work - explanation**

With `array_combine()` function you create one new array, that have keys from `$numbers` array and values from `$letters`. This function is used only because input data in 2 separate arrays. If there were used associative array at the beginning: `$data[0] => 'zero';  ... $data[1] => 'one';, ....` this function would be unnecessary.

Now because some keys may contain other keys, you need to sort your data that way that you have the longest keys before shorter ones. It makes that `10` will be changed into `ten` and not `one zero`. You can use for that `krsort()` function that sorts array using keys for compare (using array_combine our keys are now data from `$numbers` array) in reverse order using `SORT_STRING` comparison so if we have words `c, a, ccc and cc` it will sort it in reverse other (normal other is `a, c, cc, ccc`) so they will be `ccc, cc, c, a`.

At last after sorting, we need to pass data to `str_replace`. This function needs keys and values and we don't have them separate because earlier we created one array using `array_combine()` and sort it. But we can now get keys and values from that array using `array_keys()` and `array_values()` functions.

Comment: how about replacing words with images, if I have an array of words that are mostly similar, I am looking for replacing a specific word, i.e: "An" will be replaced with "Hi", and "Anh" with "Hello" and "Anha" with "Bye"

Comment: @AbuRayane Have you checked this code? It should work. For `An 1 Anha 2 Anh 21` it will give you output: `Hi one Bye two Hello twenty one`

Comment: is this the code 
`$text = 'An 1 Anha 2 Anh 21';
$numbers = array(0, 1, 2, 10, 21, ' a ', ' an ', 'An','Anh', 'Anha');
$letters = array('zero', 'one', 'two','ten','twenty one',' A ',' AN ', 'Hi', 'Hello', 'Bye');

echo str_replace($numbers, $letters, $text);`

Comment: @AbuRayane Yes, I edited my answer and added second example. I don't see any case it doesn't work. Do you? Have you tested it at all?

Comment: @AbuRayane Have you tested the whole code? Look at my answer. I don't use `$numbers` and `$letters` in my str_replace. Again - look carefully at my answer. I've added full code to **EDIT** in case you misunderstood it.

Comment: could you please explain array_combine and ksort

Comment: @AbuRayane I've added explanation to my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = 'I have 10 apples';
$numbers = array(10, 0, 1, 2);
$letters = array('ten','zero', 'one', 'two');
echo str_replace($numbers, $letters, $text);
```

but this would not be long term solution if you added more values you would need to use if statements or similar to compare before doing the replacement

Comment: If you only require positive number the below answer is better using array reverse, if you need to include negative numbers it will require more conditional checking

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it first replaces `1` by `one` then `0` by `zero`.

As suggested you can reverse the order so it will first look for higher numbers, but as also said this is a long road perhaps.

Check this question instead: [Is there an easy way to convert a number to a word in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277569/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-word-in-php)

Or, try a `preg_match`.

Or let PHP reverse the arrays:

```
$numbers = array_reverse(array(0, 1, 2,..., 10));
$letters = array_reverse(array('zero', 'one', 'two',... 'ten'));
```

Comment: The issue is not only with numbers, it might be even with words to be replace, i.e: I have two words here "Anh" and "Anha", and I would replace "Anh" with "Hello" and "Anha" with "Hi".
I think using preg_replace with specific rules will be better