# Yii2 Convert Number to words

Tags: yii2, numbers, words

Is there a way in yii2 to convert a number into words?
For example 101 into "one hundred one".
I didn't find an extension for yii2.
Is there any function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to convert a number to a word in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277569/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-word-in-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [asSpellout()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#asSpellout()-detail)

```
Yii::$app->formatter->asSpellout(101);
```

Make sure you have PHP intl extension installed.