# Numeric words in a string into numbers

Tags: php, regex

I have string:

```
$string = 'Five People';
```

I want to replace all *number*-words into numbers. So results are:

```
$string = '5 People';
```

I have this function to convert *single* words to int:

```
function words_to_number($data) {
    $data = strtr(
        $data,
        array(
            'zero'      => '0',
            'a'         => '1',
            'one'       => '1',
            'two'       => '2',
            'three'     => '3',
            'four'      => '4',
            'five'      => '5',
            'six'       => '6',
            'seven'     => '7',
            'eight'     => '8',
            'nine'      => '9',
            'ten'       => '10',
            'eleven'    => '11',
            'twelve'    => '12',
            'thirteen'  => '13',
            'fourteen'  => '14',
            'fifteen'   => '15',
            'sixteen'   => '16',
            'seventeen' => '17',
            'eighteen'  => '18',
            'nineteen'  => '19',
            'twenty'    => '20',
            'thirty'    => '30',
            'forty'     => '40',
            'fourty'    => '40', // common misspelling
            'fifty'     => '50',
            'sixty'     => '60',
            'seventy'   => '70',
            'eighty'    => '80',
            'ninety'    => '90',
            'hundred'   => '100',
            'thousand'  => '1000',
            'million'   => '1000000',
            'billion'   => '1000000000',
            'and'       => '',
        )
    );

    // Coerce all tokens to numbers
    $parts = array_map(
        function ($val) {
            return floatval($val);
        },
        preg_split('/[\s-]+/', $data)
    );

    $stack = new SplStack; // Current work stack
    $sum   = 0; // Running total
    $last  = null;

    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        if (!$stack->isEmpty()) {
            // We're part way through a phrase
            if ($stack->top() > $part) {
                // Decreasing step, e.g. from hundreds to ones
                if ($last >= 1000) {
                    // If we drop from more than 1000 then we've finished the phrase
                    $sum += $stack->pop();
                    // This is the first element of a new phrase
                    $stack->push($part);
                } else {
                    // Drop down from less than 1000, just addition
                    // e.g. "seventy one" -> "70 1" -> "70 + 1"
                    $stack->push($stack->pop() + $part);
                }
            } else {
                // Increasing step, e.g ones to hundreds
                $stack->push($stack->pop() * $part);
            }
        } else {
            // This is the first element of a new phrase
            $stack->push($part);
        }

        // Store the last processed part
        $last = $part;
    }

    return $sum + $stack->pop();
}

// test
$words = 'five';
echo words_to_number($words);
```

Works great (try it [ideone](https://ideone.com/InbVjl)). I need to find a way to determine which words within a string is a word-number and then do a replace of all these matching words and convert them into numbers.

How can this be done? Maybe a regex approach?

Comment: Note: this is *not* a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277569/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-word-in-php) thread. That thread deals with converting numbers to words. *My question* deals with finding which parts of a string that are word-numbers. I have already posted a solution to how to convert them to real numbers. I just need an approach to *find* which parts of the string that are word-numbers.

Comment: Why can't you just use `str_replace()` here?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Please explain how I would do that when I don't know which part of the string is a word-number...?

Comment: So, you plan to match any numbers in the text and then convert them into cardinal numerals? Or what kind of numbers? No fractions? Should `and` be supported between hundreds and tens?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes. The aim is to match any word-numbers in a string `five people three` and convert each word-number into a number so we end up with `5 people 3`. I see the complexity of `and` so it is not required. So I suppose the aim is to have some form of starting point to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have tried to port a [`text2num` Python library](https://github.com/ghewgill/text2num/blob/master/text2num.py) to PHP, mix it with a [regex for matching English spelled out numbers](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-trick-numbers-in-english.html#english-number-regex), [enhanced it to the decillion](https://regex101.com/r/yFXBiK/1), and here is a result:

```
function text2num($s) {
    // Enhanced the regex at http://www.rexegg.com/regex-trick-numbers-in-english.html#english-number-regex
    $reg = <<<REGEX
    (?x)           # free-spacing mode
    (?(DEFINE)
      # Within this DEFINE block, we'll define many subroutines
      # They build on each other like lego until we can define
      # a "big number"

      (?<one_to_9>  
      # The basic regex:
      # one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine
      # We'll use an optimized version:
      # Option 1: four|eight|(?:fiv|(?:ni|o)n)e|t(?:wo|hree)|
      #                                          s(?:ix|even)
      # Option 2:
      (?:f(?:ive|our)|s(?:even|ix)|t(?:hree|wo)|(?:ni|o)ne|eight)
      ) # end one_to_9 definition

      (?<ten_to_19>  
      # The basic regex:
      # ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixteen|seventeen|
      #                                              eighteen|nineteen
      # We'll use an optimized version:
      # Option 1: twelve|(?:(?:elev|t)e|(?:fif|eigh|nine|(?:thi|fou)r|
      #                                             s(?:ix|even))tee)n
      # Option 2:
      (?:(?:(?:s(?:even|ix)|f(?:our|if)|nine)te|e(?:ighte|lev))en|
                                              t(?:(?:hirte)?en|welve)) 
      ) # end ten_to_19 definition

      (?<two_digit_prefix>
      # The basic regex:
      # twenty|thirty|forty|fifty|sixty|seventy|eighty|ninety
      # We'll use an optimized version:
      # Option 1: (?:fif|six|eigh|nine|(?:tw|sev)en|(?:thi|fo)r)ty
      # Option 2:
      (?:s(?:even|ix)|t(?:hir|wen)|f(?:if|or)|eigh|nine)ty
      ) # end two_digit_prefix definition

      (?<one_to_99>
      (?&two_digit_prefix)(?:[- ](?&one_to_9))?|(?&ten_to_19)|
                                                  (?&one_to_9)
      ) # end one_to_99 definition

      (?<one_to_999>
      (?&one_to_9)[ ]hundred(?:[ ](?:and[ ])?(?&one_to_99))?|
                                                (?&one_to_99)
      ) # end one_to_999 definition

      (?<one_to_999_999>
      (?&one_to_999)[ ]thousand(?:[ ](?&one_to_999))?|
                                        (?&one_to_999)
      ) # end one_to_999_999 definition

      (?<one_to_999_999_999>
      (?&one_to_999)[ ]million(?:[ ](?&one_to_999_999))?|
                                       (?&one_to_999_999)
      ) # end one_to_999_999_999 definition

      (?<one_to_999_999_999_999>
      (?&one_to_999)[ ]billion(?:[ ](?&one_to_999_999_999))?|
                                       (?&one_to_999_999_999)
      ) # end one_to_999_999_999_999 definition

      (?<one_to_999_999_999_999_999>
      (?&one_to_999)[ ]trillion(?:[ ](?&one_to_999_999_999_999))?|
                                        (?&one_to_999_999_999_999)
      ) # end one_to_999_999_999_999_999 definition
      #  ==== MORE ====
      (?<one_to_quadrillion>
      (?&one_to_999)[ ]quadrillion(?:[ ](?&one_to_999_999_999_999_999))?|
                                        (?&one_to_999_999_999_999_999)
      ) # end one_to_quadrillion definition
      (?<one_to_quintillion>
      (?&one_to_999)[ ]quintillion(?:[ ](?&one_to_quadrillion))?|
                                        (?&one_to_quadrillion)
      ) # end one_to_quintillion definition
      (?<one_to_sextillion>
      (?&one_to_999)[ ]sextillion(?:[ ](?&one_to_quintillion))?|
                                        (?&one_to_quintillion)
      ) # end one_to_sextillion definition
      (?<one_to_septillion>
      (?&one_to_999)[ ]septillion(?:[ ](?&one_to_sextillion))?|
                                        (?&one_to_sextillion)
      ) # end one_to_septillion definition
      (?<one_to_octillion>
      (?&one_to_999)[ ]octillion(?:[ ](?&one_to_septillion))?|
                                        (?&one_to_septillion)
      ) # end one_to_octillion definition
      (?<one_to_nonillion>
      (?&one_to_999)[ ]nonillion(?:[ ](?&one_to_octillion))?|
                                        (?&one_to_octillion)
      ) # end one_to_nonillion definition
      (?<one_to_decillion>
      (?&one_to_999)[ ]decillion(?:[ ](?&one_to_nonillion))?|
                                        (?&one_to_nonillion)
      ) # end one_to_decillion definition

      (?<bignumber>
      zero|(?&one_to_decillion)
      ) # end bignumber definition

      (?<zero_to_9>
      (?&one_to_9)|zero
      ) # end zero to 9 definition

      # (?<decimals>
      # point(?:[ ](?&zero_to_9))+
      # ) # end decimals definition

    ) # End DEFINE


    ####### The Regex Matching Starts Here ########
    \b(?:(?&ten_to_19)\s+hundred|(?&bignumber))\b
REGEX;
    return preg_replace_callback('~' . trim($reg) . '~i', function ($x) {
        return text2num_internal($x[0]);
    }, $s);
}
function text2num_internal($s) {
    // Port of https://github.com/ghewgill/text2num/blob/master/text2num.py
    $Small = [
        'zero'=> 0,
        'one'=> 1,
        'two'=> 2,
        'three'=> 3,
        'four'=> 4,
        'five'=> 5,
        'six'=> 6,
        'seven'=> 7,
        'eight'=> 8,
        'nine'=> 9,
        'ten'=> 10,
        'eleven'=> 11,
        'twelve'=> 12,
        'thirteen'=> 13,
        'fourteen'=> 14,
        'fifteen'=> 15,
        'sixteen'=> 16,
        'seventeen'=> 17,
        'eighteen'=> 18,
        'nineteen'=> 19,
        'twenty'=> 20,
        'thirty'=> 30,
        'forty'=> 40,
        'fifty'=> 50,
        'sixty'=> 60,
        'seventy'=> 70,
        'eighty'=> 80,
        'ninety'=> 90
    ];

    $Magnitude = [
        'thousand'=>     1000,
        'million'=>      1000000,
        'billion'=>      1000000000,
        'trillion'=>     1000000000000,
        'quadrillion'=>  1000000000000000,
        'quintillion'=>  1000000000000000000,
        'sextillion'=>   1000000000000000000000,
        'septillion'=>   1000000000000000000000000,
        'octillion'=>    1000000000000000000000000000,
        'nonillion'=>    1000000000000000000000000000000,
        'decillion'=>    1000000000000000000000000000000000,
    ];


    $a = preg_split("~[\s-]+(?:and[\s-]+)?~u", $s);
    $a = array_map('strtolower', $a);
    $n = 0;
    $g = 0;
    foreach ($a as $w) {
        if (isset($Small[$w])) { 
            $g = $g + $Small[$w];
        }
        else if ($w == "hundred" && $g != 0) {
            $g = $g * 100;
        }
        else {
            $x = $Magnitude[$w];
            if (strlen($x) > 0) {
                $n =$n + $g * $x;
                $g = 0;
            }
            else{
                throw new Exception("Unknown number: " . $w);
            }
        }
    }
    return $n + $g;
}

echo text2num("one") . "\n";  // 1 
echo text2num("twelve") . "\n"; // 12 
echo text2num("seventy two") . "\n"; // 72 
echo text2num("three hundred") . "\n"; // 300
echo text2num("twelve hundred") . "\n"; // 1200
echo text2num("twelve thousand three hundred four") . "\n"; // 12304
echo text2num("six million") . "\n"; // 6000000
echo text2num("six million four hundred thousand five") . "\n"; // 6400005
echo text2num("one hundred twenty three billion four hundred fifty six million seven hundred eighty nine thousand twelve") . "\n"; # // 123456789012 
echo text2num("four decillion") . "\n"; // 4000000000000000000000000000000000
echo text2num("five hundred and thirty-seven") . "\n"; // 537
echo text2num("five hundred and thirty seven") . "\n"; // 537
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/jv8vc).

The regex can actually match either just big numbers or numbers like "eleven hundred", see `\b(?:(?&ten_to_19)\s+hundred|(?&bignumber))\b`. It can be further enhanced. E.g. word boundaries may be replaced with other boundary types (like `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)` to match in between whitespaces, etc.).

Decimal part in the regex is commented out since even if we match it, the `num2text` won't handle them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
\b(zero|a|one|tw(elve|enty|o)|th(irt(een|y)|ree)|fi(ft(een|y)|ve)|(four|six|seven|nine)(teen|ty)?|eight(een|y)?|ten|eleven|forty|hundred|thousand|(m|b)illion|and)+\b
```

By the way, there might be a better regex out there. Until someone posts it, you can use the following implementation

```
$regex = '/\b(zero|a|one|tw(elve|enty|o)|th(irt(een|y)|ree)|fi(ft(een|y)|ve)|(four|six|seven|nine)(teen|ty)?|eight(een|y)?|ten|eleven|forty|hundred|thousand|(m|b)illion|and)+\b/i';
function word_numbers_to_numbers($string) {
    return preg_replace_callback($regex, function($m) {
               return words_to_number($m[0]);
           },$string);
}
```

Comment: One question. Why don't you simply add the regex variable inside the function?

Comment: The use of `global` here is completely needless spaghetti.