# Identify words in a sentence which are figures through regex

Tags: regex

I am working on a regex problem where I need to identify words in the following natural language sentences which are actually figures, examples such as:

1. one hundred one plus one hundred one
2. one hundred minus one
3. hundred multiplied by one

I am trying to work out a regex which only matches the figures (such as "hundred", "one thousand and eleven" and so on) in the above statements, but am unable to do so. Here is what I have worked out so far:

If I use something like:

```
([o][n][e]|[h][u][n][d][r][e][d]).*?([o][n][e]|[h][u][n][d][r][e][d])
```

then it matches only "one hundred" in one hundred one, and if I use:

```
([o][n][e]|[h][u][n][d][r][e][d]).*([o][n][e]|[h][u][n][d][r][e][d]),
```

then it matches the whole "one hundred one plus one hundred one"

Can someone guide me as to how I should proceed here?

Comment: Please see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51422401/numeric-words-in-a-string-into-numbers/51424104#51424104), it might help.

Comment: What’s up with putting each character in its own class?!

Comment: `a regex which only matches the figures` => don't use `.`; neither `.*` nor `.*?` are appropriate in your case. Have a group that matches "number tokens" such as your first capturing group (but pleaaase write it `(one|hundred)`, those useless character classes are aggravating) and repeat that with whitespace separators, e.g. `(one|hundred)(\s+(one|hundred))*`

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: So what works for you?

Comment: I have used a combination of the info I got from the thread and the regex provided by @Aaron. Now I am able to match any number at any location in a sentence.