# How to fix my Php Function for Converting Numbers to Words outputing ten one instead of eleven, from eleven to nineteen?

Tags: php, currency

I have a problem in outputing words from eleven to nineteen, instead of eleven it outputs ten one and twelve outputs ten two and so on upto nineteen, but in decimals it correctly outputs ten to nineteen

PHP latest, Webserver

```
<?php
function toWords($num) {

  $ones = array(
    0 => "Zero",
    1 => "One",
    2 => "Two",
    3 => "Three",
    4 => "Four",
    5 => "Five",
    6 => "Six",
    7 => "Seven",
    8 => "Eight",
    9 => "Nine",
    10 => "Ten",
    11 => "Eleven",
    12 => "Twelve",
    13 => "Thirteen",
    14 => "Fourteen",
    15 => "Fifteen",
    16 => "Sixteen",
    17 => "Seventeen",
    18 => "Eighteen",
    19 => "Nineteen",
    "014" => "Fourteen"
  );
  $tens = array(
    0 => "Zero",
    1 => "Ten",
    2 => "Twenty",
    3 => "Thirty",
    4 => "Forty",
    5 => "Fifty",
    6 => "Sixty",
    7 => "Seventy",
    8 => "Eighty",
    9 => "Ninety"
  );
  $hundreds = array(
    "Hundred",
    "Thousand",
    "Million",
    "Billion",
    "Trillion",
    "Quadrillion"
  ); /*limit t quadrillion */
  $num = number_format($num, 2, ".", ",");
  $num_arr = explode(".", $num);
  $wholenum = $num_arr[0];
  $decnum = $num_arr[1];
  $whole_arr = array_reverse(explode(",", $wholenum));
  krsort($whole_arr, 1);
  $rettxt = "";
  foreach ($whole_arr as $key => $i) {

    while (substr($i, 0, 1) == "0")
      $i = substr($i, 1, 5);
    if ($i < 20) {
      /* echo "getting:".$i; */
      $rettxt .= $ones[$i];
    } elseif ($i < 100) {
      if (substr($i, 0, 1) != "0")  $rettxt .= $tens[substr($i, 0, 1)];
      if (substr($i, 1, 1) != "0") $rettxt .= " ".$ones[substr($i, 1, 1)];
    } else {
      if (substr($i, 0, 1) != "0") $rettxt .= $ones[substr($i, 0, 1)]." ".$hundreds[0];
      if (substr($i, 1, 1) != "0")$rettxt .= " ".$tens[substr($i, 1, 1)];
      if (substr($i, 2, 1) != "0")$rettxt .= " ".$ones[substr($i, 2, 1)];
    }
    if ($key > 0) {
      $rettxt .= " ".$hundreds[$key]." ";
    }
  } $rettxt = $rettxt." Pesos";
  if ($decnum > 0) {
    $rettxt .= " and ";
    if ($decnum < 20) {
      $rettxt .= $ones[$decnum];
    } elseif ($decnum < 100) {
      $rettxt .= $tens[substr($decnum, 0, 1)];
      $rettxt .= " ".$ones[substr($decnum, 1, 1)];
    }

    $rettxt = $rettxt." Centavos";
  }
  return $rettxt;
}
?>
```

The output is Ten Two instead of Twelve (eleven to nineteen) 
But in decimal it output correctly the words 
eleven to nineteen

Four Thousand Two Hundred **Ten Two** Pesos (P 4,212.00), 
One Thousand Nine Hundred **Ten Seven** Pesos and **Eighteen** Centavos (P 1,917.18)...
I fount this code at this website : https://www.studentstutorial.com/php/number-to-words.php

Comment: `echo toWords(11);` for me echos `Eleven Pesos`

Comment: @Second2None try to echo with hundreds echo toWords(111); it outputs One Hundred Ten One Pesos

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277569/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-word-in-php

Comment: You need to do things in the right order - check the special cases (eleven, twelve, …) first, and only if you did not encounter one of those values, you proceed with the “normal” stuff.

Comment: @04FS i just copied the code from the website, do you have any idea where and what part of the code was the error ?

Comment: **Do not follow studentstutorial.com tutorials!** They are advocating bad programming practices and their code samples are full of security problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$number = '11545';
$locale = 'en_US';
$format = numfmt_create($locale, NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
$in_words = numfmt_format($format, $number);

print_r($in_words);
// eleven thousand five hundred forty-five

?>
```

Comment: one hundred fifty thousand point five - 150,000.50 result
one hundred fifty thousand and fifty - 150,000 expected