# Conditional break inside of switch case

Tags: c#

I was wondering if it was possible to conditionally break out of a case in a switch statement in C#. Take the following example.

```
MediaStream photoMediaStream = null;
switch (photoSize)
{
    case PhotoSize.Normal:
        if (imageWidth >= NormalWidth && imageWidth % NormalWidth == 0)
        {
            photoMediaStream = photoMedia.GetStream(new MediaOptions {Width = NormalWidth});
            break;
        }
    case PhotoSize.Small:
        if (imageWidth >= SmallWidth && imageWidth % SmallWidth == 0)
        {
            photoMediaStream = photoMedia.GetStream(new MediaOptions {Width = SmallWidth});
            break;
        }
    case PhotoSize.Thumb:
        if (imageWidth >= ThumbWidth && imageWidth % ThumbWidth == 0)
        {
            photoMediaStream = photoMedia.GetStream(new MediaOptions {Width = ThumbWidth});
            break;
        }
}
```

Basically, if the conditional is true I want to do something and then break out of the switch statement, but if not I just want to fall through to the next case.

Comment: Did you try it? What were the results?

Comment: If `photoSize == PhotoSize.Normal` and the `if` fails surely none of the other cases would be valid anyway?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I got compiler errors for each case statement saying "Control cannot fall through from one case label to another"

Comment: do you only have 3 cases? if so, wouldn't it be acceptable to just do if...else if...else if? don't think it'd be that huge of a performance hit.

Comment: @BarryKaye Not quite. NormalWidth > SmallWidth > ThumbWidth so if case 0 is invalid theoretically case 1 or 2 could be.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you can't implicitly fall through to the next case, you must do it explicitly, using the `goto` statement. This is one of the rare cases where the use of this statement is acceptable...

```
MediaStream photoMediaStream = null;
switch (photoSize)
{
    case PhotoSize.Normal:
        if (imageWidth >= NormalWidth && imageWidth % NormalWidth == 0)
        {
            photoMediaStream = photoMedia.GetStream(new MediaOptions {Width = NormalWidth});
            break;
        }
        goto case PhotoSize.Small;
    case PhotoSize.Small:
        if (imageWidth >= SmallWidth && imageWidth % SmallWidth == 0)
        {
            photoMediaStream = photoMedia.GetStream(new MediaOptions {Width = SmallWidth});
            break;
        }
        goto case PhotoSize.Thumb;
    case PhotoSize.Thumb:
        if (imageWidth >= ThumbWidth && imageWidth % ThumbWidth == 0)
        {
            photoMediaStream = photoMedia.GetStream(new MediaOptions {Width = ThumbWidth});
            break;
        }
}
```

Anyway, it would probably be better to refactor it using `if` statements:

```
MediaStream GetPhotoMediaStream(PhotoSize photoSize, /* whatever parameters you need... */)
{
    if (photoSize == PhotoSize.Normal)
    {
        if (imageWidth >= NormalWidth && imageWidth % NormalWidth == 0)
        {
            return photoMedia.GetStream(new MediaOptions {Width = NormalWidth});
        }
        photoSize = PhotoSize.Small;
    }
    if (photoSize == PhotoSize.Small)
    {
        if (imageWidth >= SmallWidth && imageWidth % SmallWidth == 0)
        {
            return photoMedia.GetStream(new MediaOptions {Width = SmallWidth});
        }
        photoSize = PhotoSize.Thumb;
    }
    if (photoSize == PhotoSize.Thumb)
    {
        if (imageWidth >= ThumbWidth && imageWidth % ThumbWidth == 0)
        {
            return photoMedia.GetStream(new MediaOptions {Width = ThumbWidth});
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Use of `if` or `if/else` is much cleaner then constrain my self to use a `swithch/case` in a way that I have no other way then use `goto`

Comment: Thanks, I must admit I get a bit excited about a justified use for goto. Can't wait to put this in my code.

Answer (score 2):

No, C# doesn't allow fallthrough in switches, except if there is no code between the cases.
See point 8.7.2 of the C# specification:

> If the end point of the statement list of a switch section is reachable, a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: C# doesn't allow **implicit** fallthrough, but you can do it explicitly using `goto` (yeah, I know, goto is evil)...

Comment: Thanks. I think this is where I was getting confused because I had used switch statements in the past where I was falling through with no code between the cases.

Comment: @Thomas Levesque: Now that you mention it, I read about `goto case` somewhere, but forgot about it since then because I never needed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to an other case with `goto case`.

```
switch (photoSize)
{
    case PhotoSize.Normal:
        if (imageWidth >= NormalWidth && imageWidth % NormalWidth == 0)
        {
            photoMediaStream = photoMedia.GetStream(new MediaOptions {Width = NormalWidth});
            break;
        }
        goto case PhotoSize.Small;
    case PhotoSize.Small:
        if (imageWidth >= SmallWidth && imageWidth % SmallWidth == 0)
        {
            photoMediaStream = photoMedia.GetStream(new MediaOptions {Width = SmallWidth});
            break;
        }
        goto case PhotoSize.Thumb;
    case PhotoSize.Thumb:
        if (imageWidth >= ThumbWidth && imageWidth % ThumbWidth == 0)
        {
            photoMediaStream = photoMedia.GetStream(new MediaOptions {Width = ThumbWidth});
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

C# doesn't support falling through case labels when any code is in between (see [Switch statement fallthrough in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174155/switch-statement-fallthrough-in-c) ).
Thus, you surely can conditionally break - however, you will have to break at the end of each block, too, anyway ;-)

Just use some ifs instead.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible 'cause if the if condition isn't satisfied the program should flow from one case to the next one (and this isn't permitted in C#).

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Execution of the statement list in the selected section begins with
>   the first statement and proceeds through the statement list, typically
>   until a **jump statement is reached, such as a break, goto case,
>   return, or throw**. At that point, control is transferred outside the
>   switch statement or to another case label.
>
> Unlike C++, **C# does not allow execution to continue from one switch
>   section to the next**.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you need conditionise a  execution of your code in the function, do not use `switch/case`, but `if` statements chain. In the moment you want to "break" an execution flow, use `return`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, C# doesn't permit fall-through. It does permit stacking of cases, but that isn't going to help you. You could, however, achieve that using `goto` statements outside the if condition to explicitly transfer control to another (or in your case, the next) case.

*Before someone says 'OMG!! eww...goto!', I must add that there are few cases that warrant the use of gotos. This seems to be one of them. As long as not misused, there's nothing inherently wrong with gotos.*

Answer (score 0):

Put the "break" outside of If condition..

```
MediaStream photoMediaStream = null;
switch (photoSize)
{
   case PhotoSize.Normal:
    if (imageWidth >= NormalWidth && imageWidth % NormalWidth == 0)
    {
        photoMediaStream = photoMedia.GetStream(new MediaOptions {Width = NormalWidth});

    }
 break;
 case PhotoSize.Small:
    if (imageWidth >= SmallWidth && imageWidth % SmallWidth == 0)
    {
        photoMediaStream = photoMedia.GetStream(new MediaOptions {Width = SmallWidth});

    }
break;
case PhotoSize.Thumb:
    if (imageWidth >= ThumbWidth && imageWidth % ThumbWidth == 0)
    {
        photoMediaStream = photoMedia.GetStream(new MediaOptions {Width = ThumbWidth});

    }
break;
 }
```