# Cannot put "default" to switch block

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I have looked at the similar questions and answers, but i still cannot see the problem in my code. I have a switch statement and here it is:

```
switch (header)
        {
            case Headers.Queue:
                {
                    int id = pr.ReadInt32();
                    string fileName = pr.ReadString();
                    long length = pr.ReadInt64();

                    TransferQueue queue = TransferQueue.CreateDownloadQueue(this, id, Path.Combine(downloadDirectory,
                        Path.GetFileName(fileName)), length);

                    _transfers.Add(id, queue);

                    if (Queued != null)
                    {
                        Queued(this, queue);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case Headers.Start:
                {
                    int id = pr.ReadInt32();

                    if (_transfers.ContainsKey(id))
                    {
                        _transfers[id].Start();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case Headers.Chunk:
                {
                    int id = pr.ReadInt32();
                    long index = pr.ReadInt64();
                    int size = pr.ReadInt32();
                    byte[] buffer = pr.ReadBytes(size);

                    TransferQueue queue = _transfers[id];

                    queue.Write(buffer, index);

                    queue.Progress = (int)((queue.Transferred * 100) / queue.Length);
                    if (queue.LastProgress < queue.Progress)
                    {
                        queue.LastProgress = queue.Progress;

                        if (ProgressChanged != null)
                        {
                            ProgressChanged(this, queue);
                        }

                        if (queue.Progress == 100)
                        {
                            queue.Close();

                            if (Complete != null)
                            {
                                Complete(this, queue);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                {

                }
        }
```

The problem is, the default block produces an error saying that

> Control cannot fall through from one case label ('default:') to another

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: take a look at how the switch statement works http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Add a break for the default statement

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switch statement fallthrough in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174155/switch-statement-fallthrough-in-c)

Comment: I suggest that you refactor the code into a switch which simply calls  a different method for each case. That switch itself is over 60 lines long. This will make it easier for you to debug and maintain. Also, refactoring is fun! If you don't want to pollute you class namespace with three additionally functions, you can use nested functions or a dispatch dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add `break;` for the `default` case as well.

Comment: Not really, you can have `return`, `throw` etc

Comment: "You should add break;" I feel that is not true. You can add `break` sounds better IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Each `switch` case is required to have `transfer control` [`break`,`return`,`throw`] as it does not allow `fall through`.

add `break` (asper your code) for your `default` case too as beow:

```
default:
        {

        }
break;
```

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Thank you for your valuable inputs.

Comment: and you can certainly have goto and infinite loop also. Compiler will be happy to compile with that :)

Comment: :) yes yes Thank you ,but it is strange that compiler can identify the infinite loops at compile time and accepting it in place of break or return statements.

Comment: No, it does it compile time. If it can't find in compiletime it will complain you..

Comment: sorry typo ,imean in compiletime :)

Comment: Yep.. It does it usually. nothing strange. You'd have seen "unreachable code detected" warning when compiler see some infinite loop..

Comment: yes yes i see. so can we say" anyblock of code which get rid of the current case is fine to have ", please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: I'd say like this. Any statement which doesn't fall through is fine for compiler IMO.

Comment: Okay Thanks nice to meet you here :)