# What is the better pratice: duplicate code or use goto statement?

Tags: c#, goto

I'm studing C# now, and came across the following situation, what's the better pratice, duplicate the code like "EX 1" or use `goto` statement like "EX 2"? 
I don't want a personal opnion.

```
        // EX 1: 

        switch (a)
        {
            case 3:
                b = 7;
                c = 3; // duplicate code <-|
                break; //                    |
            case 4:    //                    |
                c = 3; // duplicate code --|
                break;
            default:
                b = 2;
                c = 4;
                break;
        }


        // EX 2: 

        switch (a)
        {
            case 3:
                b = 7;
                goto case 4; // not duplicate code and use goto statement
            case 4:
                c = 3;
                break;
            default:
                b = 2;
                c = 4;
                break;
        }
```

Comment: To quote the [C# language specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664749.aspx), "When execution of a switch section is to be followed by execution of another switch section, an explicit `goto case` or `goto default` statement must be used".

Comment: In this particular example (3 cases total), I would more likely use an if/else construct.

Comment: You asked a question that *requires* a personal opinion ("which is better"), and yet state you "don't want a personal opinion". Make up your mind - you can't have it both ways.

Comment: Well ideally I'd be saying a,b & c were related and so should be in a a class or a method of the class, and then factor the entire thing out. Unless it's lot of effort for very little, I like my cases to be one liners, but that's a personal preference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switch statement fallthrough in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174155/switch-statement-fallthrough-in-c)

Comment: Why put on-Hold my question? I've written "I don't want a personal opnion", So, this isn't a "based on opinions" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Example 1 pros and cons

```
+ Common structure
+ Simple to understand logic
- More lines of code
- Code repetition
```

#### Example 2 pros and cons

```
+ Fewer lines of code
+ No code repetition
- It complicates logic
- It is not commonly used in production code
```

#### Bottom line

I would prefer example 1, because, in this particular instance, the savings are minimal, but the logic gets more complicated. `Goto`, arguably, increases the chances of a bug if more people starts working on the same code, as difficulty of code increases. Let's have a look at [this embarrassing bug](http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/). Had developers not used a `goto`, there wouldn't be such a problem!

#### Bonus points

- You can use `enums` for case selection, so `case 3:` => `case CarPart.SteeringWheel`
- make sure each `case` has a `break;`
- make sure there is a `default` case
- consider using polymorphism and inheritance instead of a `switch case`

  ```
  ICarPart part1 = new SteeringWheel();
  ICarPart part2= new Mirror();
  var parts = new List<ICarPart>() {part1, part2};

  // now call your original method on the parts
  // no more need for a switch case
  ```

Comment: The bug you linked has nothing to do with `goto`, but with using `if` clauses without curly brackets. Also, using `goto` for clean-up is a common and accepted idiom in C.

Comment: It is indeed used in C a lot. But not in C#. And it is a combination of `if` and `goto`, so I wouldn't say it *has nothing to do with goto`*

Answer (score 5):

It really depends.

Is case 3 a special case of case 4?

In that situation then a goto may be in order, because if we at a later point in time add some new behaviour to case 4 then we will get that automatically for case 3 as well.

If case 3 & 4 are unrelated, then duplicating code is better.

If your real case is this small, with so few lines, I would prefer duplicating code, because of simplicity and readability.

Answer (score 1):

I personally dislike `goto` since it makes your code less easy to understand and reproduce.

I see no major issues with your first code sample as it is. If you need to, you could also split processing of `b` and `c` if that makes sense.

You should consider what is more important:

- Code readability;
- Minimal number of lines of code;
- How often does this code change? When it is changing a lot and the dependency might get lost, you probably don't want to use `goto`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, using `goto` is [considered to be bad practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_To_Statement_Considered_Harmful#Criticism_and_decline) (and rightfully so), but using `goto` solely for a forward jump out of structured control statements is usually considered to be OK, especially if the alternative is to have more complicated code.

Here's an example:

```
for (...) {
    for (...) {
        ...
        if (something)
            goto end_of_loop;
    }
}

end_of_loop:
```

[Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b942f9/acceptable-uses-for-the-goto-statement-in-C-Sharp/) you check some other acceptable usages of `goto`.

So, `goto` would be considered a bad practice. But, as I said, it still can be used.